# Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, environment-variables, path

On my fedora VM, when running with my user account I have `/usr/local/bin` in my path:

```
[justin@justin-fedora12 ~]$ env | grep PATH
 PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/justin/bin
```

And likewise when running `su`:

```
[justin@justin-fedora12 ~]$ su -
Password: 
[root@justin-fedora12 justin]# env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/justin/bin
```

However, when running via `sudo`, this directory is not in the path:

```
[root@justin-fedora12 justin]# exit
[justin@justin-fedora12 ~]$ sudo bash
[root@justin-fedora12 ~]# env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Why would the path be different when running via `sudo`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: Similar: [How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/21471)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Q: "Why would the path be different when running via sudo?"

Perhaps the best explanation is found in the `Command environment` section of `man 5 sudoers`:

> Since environment variables can influence program behavior, sudoers provides a means to restrict which variables from the user's environment are inherited by the command to be run.  There are two distinct ways sudoers can deal with environment variables.

This section goes on to explain how to modify the restrictions on environment variables that are passed - or blocked - by `sudo`. These default restrictions will vary by OS and distro. Consequently, your first stop should be `sudo -V` to learn the statusof your environment variables. Run this command from the `root` prompt; for example:

```bsh
$ sudo -i
# sudo -V

 ... a long list ...
```

This output shows each and every environment variable for your system, grouped by its status: **removed**, **preserved**, **check**.

If your `PATH` environment variable is in the **removed** list, you may change that with this line:

```
Defaults env_keep += "path PATH"
```

You may add this line to your `sudoers` file configuration by editing with:

```bsh
$ sudo visudo
```

Alternatively - and a bit *cleaner* to my way of thinking, is to add it as a [*"code snippet"*](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo#The_include_directive) to `/etc/sudoers.d` - if it exists. If it doesn't exist, you may be able to create it by adding the line `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` to the tail of your `sudoers` file.

This is basically the same process as editing `sudoers`; the *"code snippets"* may be created and edited as follows:

```bsh
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/10_mypathsnippet
```

You can verify the change is set by running `sudo -V` again (from `root` prompt!); in this case your PATH variable should now be in the **preserved** list.

Answer (score 58):

Take a look at `/etc/sudoers`. The default file in Fedora (as well as in RHEL, and also Ubuntu and similar) includes this line:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Which ensures that your path is clean when running binaries under sudo. This helps protect against some of the concerns [noted in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/). It's also convenient if you don't have `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in your own path.

Comment: Ah, I see that in my file. So, not that I want to, but if I added `/usr/local/bin` to this directive then I *would* see it in my path when running via `sudo`, right?

Comment: I just tried it and now I see `/usr/local/bin`. Thank you so much for explaining this!

Comment: What about adding your users's path for scripts and binaries, so you don't have to write the absolute path when you must `sudo` for example a script in your `~/bin` (or whatever path you use)? I just made the change - it works, only thought there might be a flip side to it?

Comment: @mattdm Yes, Ubuntu as well, as I came across that issue in Ubuntu Vivid when playing with VM. The same for [Debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16112/21471).

Comment: Very good to know; thanks! As others have [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83194/335949) you can add `env "PATH=$PATH"` to the command to temporarily bring in the current user's path for one command. For more permanent use of a command with `sudo`, rather than editing `/etc/sudoers` it might be more surgical to simply do a `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cmd cmd` inside `/usr/sbin` to link the command inside a directory already on the sudoers path. Then you can always use the command with `sudo` without pulling in all the other commands in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 11):

The command `su -` will execute the root users profile and take on that user's environment including path etc. `sudo` does not do that.

If you'd like `sudo` to behave like `su -` then use the option `sudo -i [command` which will execute the user's profile

If you'd like `su -` to behave like `sudo` then don't use the hyphen - just use `su [command]`

Answer (score 9):

You can check *why* (it's different) by running `sudo sudo -V`.

For example on Linux run:

```
$ sudo sudo -V | grep PATH
Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

<sup>Note: On macOS/BSD, just run: `sudo sudo -V`.</sup>

The above list is restricted due to default security policy plugin in some Linux distributions.

---

This is further explained in `man sudoers`:

> If the `secure_path` option is set, its value will be used for the `PATH` environment variable.
>
> `secure_path` - Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't trust the people running sudo to have a sane `PATH` environment variable you may want to use this.
>
> Another use is if you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user path”.  Users in the group specified by the `exempt_group` option are not affected by `secure_path`.  This option is not set by default.

If that's the case, you can change that by running `sudo visudo` and editing the configuration file and modifying your `secure_path` (adding extra path separated by `:`) or add your user into `exempt_group` (so you won't be affected by `secure_path` options).

Or in order to pass user's `PATH` temporary, you can run:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" my_command
```

and you can check that by:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" env | grep ^PATH
```

See also: [How to make `sudo` preserve `$PATH`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/21471)

---

Other reason why the environment could be different for `sudo`, is because you could have `env_reset` option enabled in your `sudoers` file. This causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment.

So you can use `env_keep` option (not recommended for [security reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8581/21471)) to preserve your user's environment variables:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        env_keep += "PATH PYTHONPATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

In most linuxes, you install programs via the package management, and get updates in a regular way. If you install something circumventing the package management it will be installed in /usr/local/bin (for example, or .../sbin, or /opt) and not get regular updates.

I guess therefore the programs aren't considered to be that secure, and not put into roots PATH by default.

Comment: +1 - Cool, I was wondering why it was not in the path, and that makes sense. For what it's worth, I was building node.js from scratch to play around with it, so it makes sense why it would have been put there, and why `sudo` would exclude this directory by default.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: off topic, but see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=634911

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this out for myself and I didn't see the behaviour you were seeing - my path remained the same, so maybe your sudo configuration is different. If you check `man sudoers` you'll see there is an option called `secure_path` which resets `PATH` - it sounds like this option might have been enabled.

Comment: Interesting. This was on Fedora 12, for what it's worth...

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use `sudo bash`, `bash` doesn't not act as a login shell. Try again with `sudo bash -l` and you should see the same result as `su -`.

If that is correct, then the difference in `PATH` lies in the configuration files: `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` are executed (in that order) for a login shell, while `~/.bashrc` is executed for a non-login interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I stumbled in here just now because I was investigating this exact problem.

For some reason `/usr/local/bin` was only in the PATH when becoming root via `sudo su -`. When using `sudo -i` it wasn't there. Of course I now know I can add it to /etc/sudoers, but that still didn't explain why it is already there after `su -`.  Where did this part of PATH come from?

After a lot of grepping and searching I found the answer:

**The default path containing '/usr/local/bin' is actually hardcoded in su(1).**

So no pam configuration, profile, bashrc or anything was responsible for selectively adding this element. It was always already there when `su` took over. And since `sudo` does not invoke `su` at all but uses it's own configuration, it was missing after `sudo -i`

I found this to be true on RHEL6 and RHEL7. I didn't check any other version or distribution.

Comment: Don't ask me how I verified this.. Okay, if you insist: I hex-edited a copy of the `su` binary, changed `/usr/local/bin` into something else and invoked the copy. My PATH now contained the modified string...

Good kids and non-lazy sysadmins of course just download the source and check in there. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how it was working.