# What environment do I get with sudo?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

When I run sudo, what exactly happens to my environment?

When I run `sudo command`, it doesn't seem to see my or root's environment. For example, my path for both includes `/usr/local/bin`, but if I try to run one of the program's without the full path, it fails.

I thought sudo ran as root, and hence got root`s environment. Is there a different way that bash executes under sudo than under root or my normal user?

EDIT:

I have been using `sudo -i` lately, but recently it has been causing problems because my current working directory gets set to `/root`. This is as expected (sorta), but I still don't understand why sudo isn't recognizing my executables in `/usr/local/bin`.

EDIT:

I am running Fedora 15.

Comment: What OS are you using (if Linux, what distribution)? There are (too) many ways to configure `PATH`, and sometimes it's not easy to find who overrides it last. It could be some system setting (e.g. in PAM), sudo itself, or a subsequent profile script.

Comment: @Gilles- Good point. I added my OS. I have only really noticed this on Fedora (I used to use Ubuntu), but I thought that was because they didn't add a lot of convenience setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about the defaults on Fedora, but on Debian `sudo` defaults to using the `secure_path` option with a default value of `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin`.

This means the path is changed to that value every time you use `sudo`; but when you use `sudo -i`, the path is changed after that by the root user's RC files.

Comment: I didn't know about the `secure_path` option. The default did not include `/usr/local/bin` on my install. Thanks, this really helped clear stuff up!

Answer (score 5):

You can check this quite easy with things like

Compare the output from

```
sudo env 
env
```

And things like

```
sudo whoami 
whoami
```

That way you can try to find out what is missing in your setup.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that.  Anyway, `/usr/local/bin` isn't in my sudo env, but it is in my root env and user env. Why is this?

Comment: sudo whoami returns `root`, like expected. What could be causing my sudo env to be different than my root env?

Comment: Don't know, but there must be some missing setup somewhere, /usr/local/bin is usually included. Maybe you cleared the $PATH env by mistake in some configfile?

Comment: Does sudo source /root/.bashrc? That's where I add `/usr/local/bin` to root`s path (I had to do this manually, unfortunately)?

Comment: I think you should modify your shells global config and see what happens. If you are running bash it would be something like /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: Still didn't fix it. I tried adding a line to the end of '/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile`, neither of which changed the PATH output from sudo env.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Answer (score 3):

The `sudo -i` command simulate initial login. On my Debian system, it also states that:

> This means that login-specific resource files such as
>                      .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution.  Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change
>                      to that user's home directory before running the shell.  It also initializes the environment, leaving DISPLAY and TERM unchanged, setting HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH, as
>                      well as the contents of /etc/environment on Linux and AIX systems.  All other environment variables are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust `sudo`'s `env_keep` parameter to include `PATH`, though you should keep in mind the security implications of doing that.

```
visudo
```

...will launch your `$EDITOR`, then you can make changes to `Defaults env_keep =`... as appropriate.

Also, you can add /usr/local/bin to the system's path by adding files to `/etc/profile.d`.

e.g.:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/profile.d/tjameson.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
EOF
```

Comment: `sudo` has special handling of `PATH` so you shouldn't do this.