# How can *command* work, but *sudo command* not work?

Tags: sudo

When I type the command

```
pip
```

it works fine (gives me a help page). But when I type the command

```
sudo pip
```

it gives me the response

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

whereas for example 'sudo python' works fine. How is this situation possible? I am not very familiar with what is going 'behind the scenes' when I invoke a command with sudo

Comment: Possibly related: [What environment do I get with sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/what-environment-do-i-get-with-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

There are some commands that can not be done as a normal user via sudo (ie. using cd to enter a root directory). This usually happens when the program is built-in to the shell and not a binary. You have to log in as a root user via `su`.

Alternatively, check your $PATH env variable, pip may not be located in any of those directories.