# How to set global variable visible even for sudo commands?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, java, maven

I have installed Maven on Ubuntu 16.04 following [instructions](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

I edited `/etc/environment`and added path to **maven/bin** folder to **$PATH** variable.

Under my normal user everything works just fine, but when I try to run e.g. `sudo mvn test` it tells me that **mvn** is unknown command. Restart didn't help.

Error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: mvn: not found
```

I am also little perplexed by `/bin/sh` piece - I am using bash.

So where should I put path to maven binary to make even sudo commands see it? Thank you.

Comment: Related: [What environment do I get with sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/what-environment-do-i-get-with-sudo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `sudo` your `$PATH` is getting overridden for security reasons by a line like this in your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

#### Example

Even though an entry such as this is present in `/etc/environment`:

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/tmp
```

And it appears to be picked up:

```
$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/tmp
```

And we have a script in `/tmp`:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/blah.bash
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 20 Aug  8 20:57 /tmp/blah.bash
```

And this script will print `whoami` when run:

```
$ cat /tmp/blah.bash
#!/bin/bash

whoami
```

Sudo won't let us do it:

```
$ sudo blah.bash
sudo: blah.bash: command not found
```

#### Changing sudo's secure path

But if I edit my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
$ sudo visudo
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/tmp
```

Now it works:

```
$ sudo blah.bash
root
```

#### Security

Think long and hard about why you're adding additional directories to `sudo`'s secure path. This is set up like this for a very good reason. Do not take lightly the addition of extra paths for `sudo` commands!

Adding extra directories exposes you and your users to additional risks which you many not realize until it's too late.