# Why Can't I get the path of the root user with sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, path

I've changed the PATH environment variable of the root user. The following command are there too show the PATH.

```
 su
 env | grep ^PATH
```

> PATH=/root/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/opt/distrod/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/pierre/.nix-profile/bin

But

```
 sudo env | grep ^PATH
```

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

---

What have I missed?

I know that if write

```
sudo echo $PATH
```

it doesn't work because PATH is already evaluated before changing user.
I don't think that it is a problem like this but I have no others idees

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What environment do I get with sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/what-environment-do-i-get-with-sudo)

Comment: "_I've changed the PATH environment variable of the root user._" - how?

Answer (score 0):

> What have I missed?

That sudo cleans the environment variables and only passes those that you explicitly allowed

Answer (score 0):

I think sudo uses values from the invoking user .profile while su will run things like .profile as part of switching to new ID.  I think sudo -i will get the correct PATH variable.

-i --login

```
 Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed. sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell. The command is run with an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in. The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.
```