# How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?

Tags: sudo, path

I have a program that is installed in a custom directory under /opt. To make it easier to run it, I edited my bashrc to add said directory to my path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/godi/bin:/opt/godi/sbin
```

This works fine if I want to run the program without sudo. However, if I try to run it with sudo it fails with a "command not found" error.

```
$ sudo godi_console
sudo: godi_console: command not found
```

Inspecting the PATH variable after using sudo reveals that its not including the same PATH I have as a normal user:

```
$ sudo sh
# echo $PATH                 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Why is the PATH not the same? Am I doing something wrong? I'm on Debian Jessie, if it makes a difference.

One thing I tried was to invoke /opt/godi/sbin/godi_console directly, passing the absolute path to the executable. Unfortunatelly, that didn't help in this particular case because godi_console itself depends on the PATH being correctly set.

Comment: Try `sudo -E godi_console`. `-E` means "preserve environment".

Comment: @D_Bye, that won't work if `secure_path` and/or env_reset are configured like is the case in many `sudo` deployments like on Debian.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the info - I don't use Debian, so perhaps I should just have kept quiet!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: A related question, about `su` not `sudo`, is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460478/ .

Comment: @D_Bye had the answer that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You can always do:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" godi_console
```

As a security measure on Debian, `/etc/sudoers` has the `secure_path` option set to a safe value.

Note that:

```
sudo "PATH=$PATH" godi_console
```

Where `sudo` treats leading arguments containing `=` characters as environment variable assignments by itself, would also work at running `godi_console` with *your* `$PATH` (as opposed to the `secure_path`) in its environment, but would not affect `sudo`'s search path for executable, so wouldn't help `sudo` in finding that `godi_console`.

Comment: I like this answer best since it avoids need to change settings globally (i.e. preserves principle of least privilege)

Comment: `sudo "PATH=$PATH" godi_console`  did not work in CentOs7 by the way. Needed the env

Comment: Is it okay to use `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"` as an alias for sudo?  What kind of problems could this create?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Does `sudo "PATH=$PATH" godi_console` ever really work? `sudo` accepts `VAR=value` arguments, affecting the environment of the command it runs, but unlike in `env` or `bash`, `sudo` doesn't seem to let this affect how *it* looks up the command. I only tested this (recently) on Ubuntu 16.04. But I tried adding the `exempt_group` option to `sudoers` (just for testing--I don't consider this a solution!) and the results were illuminating. Commands of the form `PATH="$PATH" sudo some-command` started working, but those of the form `sudo PATH="$PATH" some-command` *still* did not.

Comment: @EliahKagan and Hakan, you're right, I've edited the answer.

Comment: @ballsatballsdotballs. As that alias should only affect your interactive shells, that should be relatively harmless.

Comment: I just create an alias called psudo for these types of cases, where:  alias psudo="sudo env \"PATH=$PATH\"".  Then my normal sudo use is unaffected.

Answer (score 64):

You can also set the default PATH at `/etc/sudoers`

edit the file using `visudo`

and update the line to what ever you wish:
`Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Comment: This is a good way. See also https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands

Comment: At least on a RHEL system this would be better done with a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` adding onto the system default. I assume Debian would be similar.

Comment: e.g. `echo 'Defaults secure_path="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/my/custom/path"' > /etc/sudoers.d/custom_path`

Answer (score 29):

SUDO is doing env variables reset by default.

Check out its manual and option called env_reset.

You just need to disable it in /etc/sudoers.

Comment: Cool! In Ubuntu you can visudo and comment out the secure_path and env_reset lines. Makes the system considerably less secure, so beware.

Comment: Disabling `env_reset` seems not to affect `sudo`'s behaviour w/r/t PATH.

Comment: You have to comment secure_path as well, as mentioned by @RawwrBag

Answer (score 22):

This works :

```
sudo $(which your_command)
```

Example calling my `gps` script which lists Nvidia GPU's processes :

```
$ sudo gps
sudo: gps: command not found
$ sudo $(which gps)
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9922 tty7     02:42:47 Xorg
```

Explanation :

```
$ set -x;sudo $(which gps);set +x
++ which gps
+ sudo /home/xyztuv/myScripts/shl/gps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9922 tty7     02:42:39 Xorg
+ set +x
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't expose you to other commands on your path being hijacked. All of the other answers here risk running other executables as root.

Comment: Unless the command you're using calls other commands that it expects to find in $PATH - then you want to be "hijacked", and so the other answers are better.

Comment: @DaveMorse Yes, in that sense, my example is not secure but then the question of `How to make "sudo" preserve $PATH?` is not a secure idea either.

Comment: using absolute path avoid PATH problem. in general purpose a smart move

Comment: I don't know that it's the best answer. It's a good answer. The reason why is some scripts start with something like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and this answer won't help make sure you get the right python3, like for a virtual environment.

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo --preserve-env=PATH env [command]
```

this ovverrides secure_path on my end

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me on Ubuntu.

Put this near the bottom of your ~/.bashrc:

```
mysudo() {
        cmd=$(which $1)
        shift
        sudo "$cmd" $@
}

alias sudo="mysudo"
```

Then log out and log back in, or do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that sudo works properly, like it does on other distros such as Debian.

On second thought, this is not supporting sudo's command line switches, so if you need those, you could expand on this and make something a bit more complex to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not precisely what OP asks for, but this might help:

```
sudo -u the_user sh -c 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/godi/bin echo $PATH'
```

This changes the PATH *inside* the sudoed command.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
sudo "PATH=$PATH" [your command]
```

Do not change $PATH with your path value, you just write it this way

example: `$ sudo env "PATH=$PATH" ant -f webAppConfig.xml regenWebAppConf....`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this might not entirely be what op wants, I believe the best option is to call

`sudo /opt/godi/sbin/godi_console`

That way you are certain you are calling the correct binary, and not one that someone sneaked into your path somewhere.