# Why is PATH reset in a sudo command?

Tags: security, sudo, path

After much frustrating head-brick-wall contact, I've discovered this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/steve/bin

$ sudo bash
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

but

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

$ sudo bash -Ec 'echo $PATH'
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I gather from [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path) that the `sudo` path is read from `/etc/sudoers` — but why? Does setting `$PATH` in `/root/.profile` make any sense, or is that just a recipe for the confusion above (ie, spawning an actual shell causes a different `$PATH` from that used in casual `sudo` commands...)?

I'm using bash on RHEL 6.4.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Protections

`sudo` has builtin protections that you're noticing when you run several of these commands. These protections are doing a number of things, such as enforcing  a safe `$PATH`.

From the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

This is what's showing up when you run your `sudo -c ....` commands.  You can disable this behavior with the `-E` switch to `sudo`.

**NOTE:** For some setups the `-E` switch will not work. To "workaround" it you can use `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" bash`. This will also carry your current `$PATH` forward to your `sudo` environment.

#### interactive vs. login

When you ran this command:

```
$ sudo bash
```

You ran a interactive `bash` shell vs. a login `bash` shell. This has to do with how `bash` sources it's configuration files.

- *interactive, aka `bash` or `bash -i`*, sources `$HOME/.bashrc`
- *login, aka `bash -l`*, sources `$HOME/.bash_profile`

#### So why doesn't `-E` work?

TylerRick's answer to this SO question [(sudo changes PATH - why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375780/33204) covers a lot of the reasons as to why. The main is that it's typically hardcoded when `sudo` is compiled, as is the case with Ubuntu, resulting in these switches as being useless. There have been long open issues in Launchpad regarding these and they've never been fixed, leaving us with the realization that Canonical thinks it's better to leave this behavior as the default.

- [Ubuntu bug #50797 ("sudo built with --with-secure-path is problematic")](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/50797)
- [Ubuntu bug #192651 ("sudo path is always reset")](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/192651/)
- [Ubuntu bug #226595 ("impossible to retain/specify PATH")](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/226595)

Comment: Thanks for the PATH=$PATH workaround - which does work. Are you able to explain why -E doesn't work for "some setups"? Presumably because the PATH-resetting behaviour of sudo is activated after -E is applied?

Comment: @SteveBennett - see updates as to why.

Answer (score 5):

When a rule in `sudoers` authorizes a user to run a specific command `wibble`, it is often necessary to set `PATH` to a safe value: one that only contains directories where the user cannot plant his own programs. If `wibble` called the external command `foo`, and `PATH` was not reset, then the user could put `~/bin` at the front of his `PATH`, link `/bin/sh` to `~/bin/foo` and then run `sudo wibble` to invoke `~/bin/foo` which lets him type arbitrary shell commands.

Resetting PATH is therefore a safe default. While it is not necessary in all cases, it is a lot easier and safer to make that the default setting.

When a rule in `sudoers` authorizes a user to run arbitrary commands, resetting PATH has no direct security advantage. There is an indirect advantage, which is that the user may accidentally have set a PATH containing potentially harmful programs, and resetting PATH avoids risking that these programs are called accidentally. There is also a functional advantage: it is common to need to have `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` when running commands as root but not to have them as an ordinary user.

If you don't want the path to be reset when you run `sudo`, add yourself to the exempt group in `sudoers`:

```
Defaults exempt_group+=stevebennet
```

If you run a login shell (`sudo -I` or `sudo bash -l` or other method), that shell typically reads `.profile` in the target user's home directory, and that file may change PATH.

Answer (score 1):

That's for security reasons. The PATH is set to a well defined one and not to whatever hacked PATH the source user might be having.

See https://superuser.com/questions/98686/passing-path-through-sudo for kind of a workaround.