# how to pass environment variable to sudo su

Tags: linux, sudo, environment-variables, su

I basically need to do this:

```
DUMMY=dummy
sudo su - ec2-user -c 'echo $DUMMY'
```

This doesn't work. How can I pass the env variable $DUMMY to su? -p doesn't work with -l.

Comment: What about simply `sudo -iu ec2-user echo $DUMMY`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make \`sudo\` preserve $PATH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do it without calling login shell:

```
sudo DUMMY=dummy su ec2-user -c 'echo "$DUMMY"'
```

or:

```
sudo DUMMY=dummy su -p - ec2-user -c 'echo "$DUMMY"'
```

The `-p` option of `su` command preserve environment variables.

Comment: I think "-E" preserves environment variables http://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html

Comment: @Andy But it's often forbidden by the sudo configuration.

Comment: There are other threads that says `-m` preserves the variable, other says `-c` whats the difference? And one of the comment in this answer days `-E` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488758/how-do-you-give-su-the-current-user-environment-variables

Comment: @Vishrant `-m` and `-p` are the same, `-c` does not. `-E` is for `sudo`, not `su`.

Comment: Thanks @cuonglm, I would appreciate and will be helpful for others too, if you can update your answer with these details.

Comment: This answer is better than `-E` when you only want to preserve _one_ environment variable.

Comment: The second snippet doesn't and mustn't work as the man says that `-p` is ignored when `--login` is used. So for the second case one should put env variables to a user shell profile.

Answer (score 76):

Pro tip: [There is never really a good reason to run `sudo su`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222). To run a command as a different user, use `sudo -u username command`. If you want a root shell, run `sudo -i` or `sudo -l`. If you have activated the root account, you can also run `su` alone, but `sudo su` is just not useful. And yes, I know you see it everywhere.

That said, `sudo` has the `-E` switch which will preserve the environment of the user's session:

```
 -E, --preserve-env
        Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve 
        their existing environment variables.  The security policy may
        return an error if the user does not have permission to 
        preserve the environment.
```

So, you will first need to export your variable, and then run `sudo -E`:

```
$ export DUMMY=dummy
$ sudo -Eu bob bash -c 'echo $DUMMY'
dummy
```

The `bash -c` is not needed. However, if I run `sudo -Eu bob echo "$DUMMY"`, the variable is expanded before the root shell is launched so it doesn't demonstrate that the command actually works:

```
$ sudo -u bob echo $DUMMY  ## looks like it works but doesn't
dummy
$ sudo -u bob bash -c 'echo D:$DUMMY' ## now we see it failed
D:
$ sudo -Eu bob bash -c 'echo D:$DUMMY'  ## works as expected
D:dummy
```

Comment: A better way to preserve an environment variable is to add it to `env_keep` in `sudoers`.  Perhaps like this: `Defaults env_keep += "DUMMY"`.

Comment: @lcd047 but that will preserve the environment for _all_ invocations of `sudo`. It is also more cumbersome for a single variable. That is only useful for something that should always be exported.

Comment: Yes, it's a trade-off, but not all environment variables are equally harmful.  There's a substantial difference between carrying over `LD_PRELOAD` and carrying over `LESSCHARDEF`.  I don't think convenience should be the winning argument here...

Comment: @lcd047 your suggestion is certainly worth posting as an answer. My point is that it's not practical for exporting arbitrary variables. Yes, if there's a specific variable you always want exported, that's the way to go but not if you want to do this once and for a variable defined in the same session.

Answer (score 12):

-E does the job for me.
From man `sudo` -

> **`-E`**, **`--preserve-env`**
>   Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to pre‐
>                    serve their existing environment variables.  The security
>                    policy may return an error if the user does not have permis‐
>                    sion to preserve the environment.

Comment: Unfortunately it will only do the job if your admin did not restrict you from using -E.

Answer (score 3):

Also `su` has a `--whitelist-environment` option. It can be used like so:

```
# export DUMMY=dummy
# export FOO=foo
# su -l somebody --whitelist-environment="DUMMY,FOO"
$ env
...
PWD=/home/somebody
LOGNAME=somebody
HOME=/home/somebody
...
DUMMY=dummy
FOO=foo
...
```

Don't forget to `export` the whitelisted variables.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and I fixed by exporting env variable into profile. below is my sample code:

```
echo export runner_token=$(echo $resp_json | jq -r '.token') >> /etc/profile
su -p - ubuntu -c '$HOME/actions-runner/config.sh --url https://github.com/${gh_repo_user}/${gh_repo_name} --token "$runner_token"  --name MAC-AWS-RUNNER --labels ${gh_runner_labels}'
```

Answer (score 0):

What follows is a solution that does not need one to change the security policy.

*I will ignore the `su` part, as we can use the `--user` option of `sudo`.*

We want to pass environment variables to a `command` run via `sudo`. However `sudo` will not allow environment variables to be passed to a command (there are valid security reason for this, some variables can be dangerous). A shell can be used to set environment variables, and `sudo` can run a shell with a script passed to it. Therefore tell `sudo` to run a script that sets the environment variables.

```
var_a=someThing
var_b=someOtherThing

sudo bash -c "
    export var_a=\"${var_a}\"
    export var_b=\"${var_b}\"

    the_command some_args
"
```