# Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?

Tags: shell, sudo, environment-variables, su

To launch a root shell on machines where the root account is disabled, you can run one of:

- `sudo -i` : run an interactive login shell (reads `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile`)
- `sudo -s` : run a non-login interactive shell (reads `/root/.bashrc`)

In the Ubuntu world, I very often see `sudo su` suggested as a way to get a root shell. Why run two separate commands when one will do? As far as I can tell, `sudo -i` is equivalent to `sudo su -` and `sudo -s` is the same as `sudo su`.

The only differences seem to be (comparing `sudo -i` on the left and `sudo su -` on the right):

[image: screenshot of meld comparing 'sudo -i' and 'sudo su -']

And comparing `sudo -s` (left) and `sudo su` (right):

[image: screenshot of meld comparing 'sudo -s' and 'sudo su']

The main differences (ignoring the `SUDO_foo` variables and `LS_COLORS`) seem to be the `XDG_foo` system variables in the `sudo su` versions.

Are there any cases where that difference warrants using the rather inelegant `sudo su`? Can I safely tell people (as I often have) that there's never any point in running `sudo su` or am I missing something?

Comment: I've never understood those fancy systems like `ubuntu` which prevent users from standard `su -`. They created problem and now there are endless discussions on how to solve it.

Comment: @jimmij Don't you need to know root password with `su -`? Don't you think that poses a security hole in multi-user environments, where more than one person needs to have root access?

Comment: @Christopher The problem is not one of the user that have sudo privilege or the root password to hack the system. The problem is about password safety. When you change the root password, you need to let all users who needs it to know, which can be difficult. With sudo, you don't have this difficulty.

Comment: What is the diff tool?

Comment: @Christopher I do think that there is a difference in security in not having to distribute a shared password. With `sudo`, a users root enabling password never has to leave their control. (We do not live in a world where people refrain from insecure password practices, especially when it involves sending it to others.) Apart from that, it is useful to be able to restrict users to only being able to run a few commands with `sudo`, if all a user needs root access for is to restart a service, why give them full root access?

Comment: @jimmij How does Ubuntu prevent the use of `su -`? Yes, one would have to set a root password, but that's trivial.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can configure `sudo` and prevent a root password.

Comment: @Christopher I didn't say it was a security hole. I said it was a difference. I took the prior use of security hole as being a lack of the precise terminology you may find to be fitting.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Ubuntu does not have one set by default, but it is not prevented. Preventing a user with full root access from setting a root password would require something restricting root's privileges. Users can be given limited access to what they can do as root via sudo, see [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Comment: @JoshTheGeek (off-topic) that's [meld](http://meldmerge.org/).

Comment: @Erathiel - you don't have to distribute a shared password to use a root account. That's what PAM is for. And even without it, that's what groups are for.

Comment: @mikeserv You're right, there are options, as is always the case with *NIX. Still, `sudo` gets the job done in probably the cleanest way.

Comment: @Erathiel - that's completely incorrect. `sudo` is insane - it *always* has been. It accepts *shell globs* to identify users! And PAM is *way* more secure.

Comment: What about `sudo bash` (or the shell of your choice)? have you matched differencies with the rest of the commands? It should match better with `sudo -i` shouldn't it?

Comment: @YoMismo the environments (as reported by `env`) of `sudo -s` (which runs `$SHELL` as root) and `sudo bash` are 100% identical.

Comment: I assume you're *only* asking about cases where you want to become the root user, correct? `sudo su` is extremely useful for becoming a *non-root* user.

Comment: @KyleStrand yes, this was more about root but there's even less of a reason to ever do `sudo su user`.  Just do `sudo -iu user` instead.

Comment: @terdon Huh, I was unaware of the `-u` flag for `sudo`. Semantically, though, I still prefer `sudo su` -- "as a super user (`su-`), run (`-do`) a single command: switch users (`su`)." Plus it's simpler to type on a standard QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: dhag's selected answer says: sudo -s reads .bashrc of the calling user. That conflicts with the terdon's answer which says sudo -s reads /root/.bashrc. Which is it?

Comment: I would never do it, but if you are 100% sure that you will never have code on your system that calls `su` then i would just remove it.  Reason: security. More programs with with SUID rights means more attack vectors.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As you stated in your question, the main difference is the environment.

## `sudo su -` vs. `sudo -i`

In case of `sudo su -` it is a login shell, so `/etc/profile`, `.profile` and `.bashrc` are executed and you will find yourself in root's home directory with root's environment.

`sudo -i` is nearly the same as `sudo su -` The `-i` (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.login` will be read and executed by the shell.

## `sudo su` vs. `sudo -s`

`sudo su` calls `sudo` with the command `su`. Bash is called as interactive non-login shell. So `bash` only executes `.bashrc`. You can see that after switching to root you are still in the same directory:

```
user@host:~$ sudo su
root@host:/home/user#
```

`sudo -s` reads the `$SHELL` variable and executes the content. If `$SHELL` contains `/bin/bash` it invokes `sudo /bin/bash`, which means that `/bin/bash` is started as non-login shell, so all the dot-files are not executed, but `bash` itself reads .`bashrc` of the calling user. Your environment stays the same. Your home will not be root's home. So you are root, but in the environment of the calling user.

## Conclusion

The `-i` flag was added to `sudo` in [2004](https://www.sudo.ws/sudo/changes.html), to provide a similar function to `sudo su -`, so `sudo su -` was the template for `sudo -i` and meant to work like it. I think it doesn't really matter which you use, unless the environment isn't important.

## Addition

A basic point that must be mentioned here is that `sudo` was designed to run only **one single command** with higher privileges and then drop those privileges to the original ones. It was never meant to really **switch** the user and leave open a root shell. Over the time, `sudo` was expanded with such mechanisms, because people were annoyed about why to use `sudo` in front of every command.

So the meaning of `sudo` was abused. `sudo` was meant to encourage the user to minimize the use of root privileges.

What we have now, is `sudo` becomes more and more popular. It is integrated in nearly every well known linux distribution. The original tool to switch to another user account is `su`. For an old school *nix veteran such thing like `sudo` might seem needless. It adds complexity and behaves more likely to the mechanisms we know from Microsofts os-family, and thus is in contrary to the philosophy of simplicity of *nix systems.

I'm not really a veteran, but also in my opinion `sudo` was always a thorn in my side, from the time is was introduced and I always worked around the usage of `sudo`, if it was possible. I am most reluctant to use `sudo`. On all my systems, the root account is enabled. But things change, maybe the time will come, when `su` will be deprecated and `sudo` replaces `su` completely.

Therefore I think, it will be the best to use `sudo`'s internal mechanisms (`-s`, `-i`) instead of relying on an old tool such as `su`.

Comment: Ah, so before 2004 there was actually a reason to run `sudo su` then? At the time I was using distros without sudo and active root accounts so I don't know. That might explain the prevalence of the sudo su meme in the Ubuntu world.

Comment: I never knew about `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` before - I've been running UNIXes of various sorts since 1991 and for me `sudo su -` is just an ingrained habit at this point.

Comment: Is `sudo -s` the same as `sudo $SHELL` then?

Comment: @fluffy that's interesting. Were these systems with no active root account? Couldn't you just run `su` alone? I was running RH-based systems until around 2006 and had never seen `sudo` in the 6 or 7 years I'd been using Linux before that.7

Comment: @terdon These were shared systems (both Linux and otherwise) where I had `sudo` access but didn't have the root password. Not every Linux (or UNIX) machine is totally under the control of the person sitting at it. :)

Comment: (Agreeing with @chaos) The reasons to use `sudo su -` are 1) that it works and you know exactly what it does, and 2) that you don't have to remember another option to `sudo` (when you already know `su -`) and 3) you don't have to remember which version of `sudo` you're working with at the moment.  Why remember one more piece of trivia when what you already have works fine?  Is there anything that `su -i` does better other than avoid a log entry?  I don't use `sudo su -` enough to worry about that.

Comment: Chaos, could you add a conclusion that takes a position about whether or not there's any point in running `sudo su`? The main point you seem to be making, apart from the comparison, is that no, there's no reason to run `sudo su` unless you are running a system whose `sudo` is more than 11 years old. Is that correct?

Comment: @terdon I see, in the end I was a bit rare in words =) I tried to complete my answer a bit and hope it makes things more clear.

Comment: Thanks :) And I quite agree. I used to use `su` all the time until I switched to Debian-based systems and discovered `sudo`.

Comment: "Your home will not be root's home" (for `sudo -s`) - I believed this too, but the env's shown in the question don't bear it out!  (Nor testing).  Still, if I know `sudo -i` is supposed to work, it seems best to avoid stacking `sudo` and `su`.

Comment: I just saw the update, very nice! For the record, let me state that I too cut my *nix teeth on systems with no `sudo` and am very used to `su`. It's the combination of the two that bugs me.

Comment: terdon's highest rated answer says: sudo -s : reads /root/.bashrc, which conflicts with chaos's answer that says sudo -s reads .bashrc of the calling user. Which is it?

Comment: @chaos `sudo -s` reads `/root/.bashrc`, the environment does not remain the same. I just tried `sudo -s` and then `echo $HOME` and got `/root`. The only env variable that seems to have been carried over is `PATH` which I explicitly `export`.

Comment: `It [sudo] was never meant to really switch the user and leave open a root shell.`   I was not aware that this was possible - I have only ever used `sudo` in the "one command at a time" mode. Just so I'm clear, do `sudo su` and `sudo su -`, etc all create & leave open a root shell?

Comment: @Seamus Yes they do

Comment: That would seem to defeat the purpose of `sudo` in the first place - but perhaps you do not agree with this?

Comment: @Seamus This is probabily a philosophical question, but sudo was invented to execute a "command" with elevated privileges and drop them afterwards. Nobody stops you if that "command" is a shell. Btw, I use these commands in the answer myself as well.

Comment: Umm - yes, but a poorly-worded one. I'd never actually considered using `sudo` in that way. I can only *imagine* that it defeats the purpose - because, of course, I am not the author of `sudo` & don't actually know the purpose from a first-hand account. I have learned something here & therefore appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: @Seamus No, `sudo -i` does not defeat the purpose of sudo; the answer left out the _other_ (and IMHO more) important purpose of sudo which is to allow easily enabling and disabling root access (whether for one command or a session) on a per-user basis. With `su` all users with root access must know and share the root password, which is inconvenient, and it's even more inconvenient to change it every time you want to remove a user's root access. With `sudo` users use their own password and a config file determines if they're allowed to do things as root.

Answer (score 22):

To answer your question directly: no, there is no good reason to do this.  Also, sudo su produces two log entries when one would suffice.

I've seen many people do this, and when I ask why they don't just run `sudo -s`, the answer is just that they don't know about the `-s` flag to sudo, and generally they switch after I point it out.

However, to your list of `sudo -s` and `sudo -i`, I'd like to add one more option, `sudo -sE`, which is kind of a replacement for `su -m`.  `sudo -sE` preserves your environment including home directory.  This has risks if your home directory is insecure (on NFS).  But in an environment where many people use root, it saves you from having to agree on the contents of the root `.bashrc` file.  My `.bashrc` contains many specializations for root, so I don't get exactly the same environment as root, but at least I get exactly the environment I want.

Comment: If it preserves your environment, including `$HOME`, that means all new files created under the home folder are owned by root, not by you. I've had this cause many hard to diagnose permission errors.

Comment: `sudo -sE` and then `echo $HOME` gives `/root` on CentOS 7, bash 4.2. `-sE` does not appear to preserve home directory as you stated.

Comment: Using LinuxMint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18.04.1), `$HOME` is the user's home directory, not `/root`.

Comment: You can determine in the sudo configuration file exactly what environment variables are preserved, set or reset with the various `env_*` configuration options. And these of course can be applied on a per-user basis, per-command basis, or various other ways. So there's no problem with having `$HOME` set or preserved, as per your preference for whatever particular command you're running.