# When can a user do `sudo su` but not `sudo su -`?

Tags: sudo, su

The following happened to me:

```
$ sudo su - superman

Sorry, user clarkkent is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - superman' as root in krypton101.
```

However the following worked fine:

```
$ sudo su superman
```

When is it useful to allow a user to do `sudo su` but not `sudo su -`? How is this setting set / unset? I read [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/453988/whats-the-difference-between-su-with-and-without-hyphen) but it didn't help.

More details:

- I am not the administrator
- I don't have access to `/etc/sudoers`
- the distribution is Centos 7

Comment: Is this your personal machine or does someone else administer it? Can you see the contents of `/etc/sudoers`? If so, [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo grep -w su /etc/sudoers`. Also [edit] and add your distribution.

Comment: Relevant: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169)

Comment: `sudo -l` will be helpful, it will show what commands you're allowed to execute even if you can't read `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Answer (score 3):

When specifying commands allowed via `sudo`, there are basically two easy options:

- allow a specific command with *any* parameters, or
- allow a specific command with an *exactly specified* set of parameters only.

As a result, allowing both `sudo su - superman` and `sudo su superman` requires two entries in the `sudoers` file. It looks like your administrator has only provided you with one of them.

The `sudoers` file syntax does not really let the administrator specify a specific command with wildcard- or regexp-limited options, because those specifications would be an all too easy to abuse. As Andrew said, *better safe than sorry* is the approach here.

However, note that `sudo su superman` requires `sudo` to allow the original user to run `su superman` *as root*. Effectively, there will be two identity transitions instead of just one: first from original user to root by `sudo` and then from root to `superman` by `su`. The specification would look like this in the `sudoers` file:

```
original_user ALL=(root) su superman
```

On the other hand, the `sudoers` syntax has a much easier way to allow the user to run any commands as a specific user, if the user is not too fixated to the use of the `su` command.

If the sudoers specification is written like this:

```
original_user ALL=(superman) ALL
```

then the user can use `sudo -u superman -s` to achieve a close (but possibly not exact) equivalent of `sudo su superman` *and* `sudo -u superman -i` to achieve an **exact** equivalent of `sudo su - superman`.

Why people don't use this, but instead insist on using `sudo su -` constructs? *Because the `-i` option did not exist in older versions of `sudo`!*

It only appeared sometime after year 2000, so there's plenty of old literature that still recommends the now-obsolete `sudo su -` construction.  And of course, old Unix users and administrators may have that in muscle memory, so they'll use it without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: When is it useful to allow a user to do sudo su but not sudo su -?

The hyphen after `su` but before the *username* instructs su to allow the current user to inherit the environment of username.  As long as *clarkkent's* environment has the necessary environment variables set to be able to run as *superman*, it is not necessary to run `sudo su - superman`.

A plausible 'reason' NOT to allow `sudo su - superman` may be that the system administrator believed `sudo su - superman` created a security risk.  This is because `sudo su -`,  without specifying a username, instructs the system to log you in as *root* user, which is likely something the system administrator is trying to avoid. I do not actually know for certain adding the hyphen creates this risk, or not, but I guess when it comes to security, it's *better safe than sorry*.

How is this setting set / unset?

The configuration is defined in the `/etc/sudoers` file.