# How can I have a root login shell with sudo?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, login

My user is part of the `admin` group and I'm used to type `sudo su` to impersonate root.
Unfortunately this generate a `non-login` shell and if I need one I need to type again `/bin/bash -l`.

Is there any way to have a login shell directly running a `sudo` command?

Answer (score 9):

`sudo -i` will give you a login shell.

See the `sudo` manual.

About `sudo su`, see "[Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)".

Comment: `$ sudo -i` results in `This account is currently not available.` (because of `usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin root`)

Comment: @luckydonald You should ask a new question about this.