# bash - su and $HOME

Tags: sudo, su, home

Assume we have two users: user1 (an admin) and user2 (a standard user)

- Login as user1
- Run

  ```
  sudo su - user2 -c "env"
  ```
- The result shows $HOME=/home/user2
- Run

  ```
  sudo su - user2 -c "echo $HOME"
  ```
- The result shows $HOME=/home/user1

Why is that?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Comment: `sudo su` is a useless use of `su`. `sudo` already grants you root access, you don't need `su` to do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in the second example, the variable `$HOME` gets expanded before the shell executes the command, so what you are really running is

```
sudo su - user2 -c "echo /home/user1"
```

as that is the value the variable `$HOME` has at this point.

(I also guess the output of the second command is not really  `$HOME=/home/user1` but instead just `/home/user1`).

You could prevent variable expansion in the first shell if you use single quotes:

```
$ sudo su - user2 -c 'echo $HOME' 
/home/user2
```

Comment: AS sven already mentioned. Use single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Sven. I do need variable expansion. If I want to change $HOME when run a command as user2 what can I do?  
I've tried `sudo su - user2 -c "HOME=aaa echo $HOME"` but it still returns `$HOME=/home/user1`

Comment: That is the same problem. Now you are running `... -c "HOME=aaa echo /home/user1"` ...  Another option to prevent the expansion would be to escape the `$` like so: `... -c "echo \$HOME"`. This would tell the shell that you want to ignore the special meaning of the `$` character and send it down to the `su` command to execute.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You don't want `user1`'s home to be expanded and with the escape, this doesn't happen. Instead, the command `echo $HOME` is send to the shell that runs in `user2`s context and there the variable *is* expanded to `/home/user2`. If that still doesn't solve your problem, please ask a new question explaining the whole context of your task because I've answered this question ("Why does this happen").

Comment: To be clear: `sudo su - user2 -c "echo \$HOME"` will result in `"/home/user2"`. The expansion is prevent in the context of `user1` and the `sudo` command, but not in the context of `user2`.

Comment: Thanks Sven, I **do need expansion** as stated because inside `-c` is actually a complex script. Reading your answer carefully `-c "echo \$HOME"` actually works for me! Thanks