# How does bash file redirection to standard in differ from shell (`sh`) on Linux?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdin, dash

I wrote a script which switches users while running, and executed it using file redirection to standard in.  So `user-switch.sh` is...

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami
sudo su -l root
whoami
```

And running it with `bash` gives me the behavior I expect

```
$ bash < user-switch.sh
vagrant
root
```

However, if I run the script with `sh`, I get different output

```
$ sh < user-switch.sh 
vagrant
vagrant
```

Why is `bash < user-switch.sh` giving different output than `sh < user-switch.sh`?

### Notes:

- happens on two different boxes running Debian Jessie

Comment: Not an answer, but regarding `sudo su`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Comment: is /bin/sh = dash on Debian? I can't repro on RHEL where /bin/sh = bash

Comment: `/bin/sh` on (my copy of) Debian is Dash, yes.  I didn't even know what that was until just now.  I've stuck with bash until now.

Comment: The *bash* behavior isn't guaranteed to work by any documented semantics either.

Comment: Someone pointed out to me today that the script I was running violated the semantics of how bash is intended to be used.  There were a couple great answers to this question, but it's worth pointing out that one probably shouldn't be switching users mid script.  I originally tried `user-switch.sh` in a Jenkins job, and it the script executed.  Running the same script outside of Jenkins produced different results, and I resorted to file redirection to get the behavior I saw in Jenkins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A similar script, without `sudo`, but similar results:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/^/--/'
whoami

$ bash < script.sh
--whoami

$ dash < script.sh
itvirta
```

With `bash`, the rest of the script goes as input to `sed`, with `dash`, the shell interprets it.

Running `strace` on those: `dash` reads a block of the script (eight kB here, more than enought to hold the whole script), and then spawns `sed`:

```
read(0, "#!/bin/bash\nsed -e 's/^/--/'\nwho"..., 8192) = 36
stat("/bin/sed", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=73416, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|...
```

Which means that the filehandle is at the end of the file, and `sed` will not see any input. The remaining part being buffered within `dash`. (If the script was longer than the block size of 8 kB, the remaining part would be read by `sed`.)

Bash, on the other hand, seeks back to the end of the last command:

```
read(0, "#!/bin/bash\nsed -e 's/^/--/'\nwho"..., 36) = 36
stat("/bin/sed", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=73416, ...}) = 0
...
lseek(0, -7, SEEK_CUR)                  = 29
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|...
```

If the input comes from a pipe, as here:

```
$ cat script.sh | bash
```

rewinding cannot be done, as pipes and sockets are not seekable. In this case, Bash falls back to reading the input *one character at a time* to avoid overreading. ([`fd_to_buffered_stream()` in `input.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/input.c#n396)) Doing a full system call for each byte is not very effective in principle. In practise, I don't think the reads will be a great overhead compared e.g. to the fact that most things the shell does involve spawning whole new processes.

A similar situation is this:

```
echo -e 'foo\nbar\ndoo' | bash -c 'read a; head -1'
```

The subshell has to make sure `read` only reads up the the first newline, so that `head` sees the next line. (This works with `dash` too.)

---

In other words, Bash goes to additional lengths to support reading the same source for the script itself, and for commands executed from it. `dash` doesn't. The `zsh`, and `ksh93` packaged in Debian go with Bash on this.

Comment: Frankly, I'm a bit surprised that works.

Comment: thanks for the great answer!  I'll run both commands using `strace` later and compare the outputs.  I hadn't though to use that approach.

Comment: Yeah, my reaction on reading the question was surprise that it *does* work with bash — I had it filed away as something that definitely wouldn't work. I guess I was only half right :)

Answer (score 12):

The shell is reading the script from standard input. Inside the script, you run a command which also wants to read standard input. Which input is going to go where? **You can't tell reliably**.

The way shells work is that they read a chunk of source code, parse it, and if they find a complete command, run the command, then proceed with the remainder of the chunk and the remainder of the file. If the chunk doesn't contain a complete command (with a terminating character at the end — I think all shells read up to the end of a line), the shell reads another chunk, and so on.

If a command in the script tries to read from the same file descriptor that the shell is reading the script from, then the command will find whatever comes after the last chunk that it read. This location is unpredictable: it depends on what chunk size the shell picked, and that can depend not only on the shell and its version but on the machine configuration, available memory, etc.

Bash seeks to the end of a command's source code in the script before executing the command. This is not something that you can count on, not only because other shells don't do it, but also because this only works if the shell is reading from a regular file. If the shell is reading from a pipe (e.g. `ssh remote-host.example.com <local-script-file.sh`), data that's been read is read and can't be unread.

If you want to pass input to a command in the script, you need to do so explicitly, typically with a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). (A here document is usually the most convenient for multi-line input, but any method will do.) The code you wrote only works in a few shells, only if the script is passed as input to the shell from a regular file; if you expected that the second `whoami` would be passed as input to `sudo …`, think again, keeping in mind that most of the time the script is not passed to the shell's standard input.

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
sudo su -l root <<'EOF'
whoami
EOF
```

Note that this decade, you can use `sudo -i root`. Running `sudo su` is a hack from the past.