# This user is currently not available - but allow to run script by this user

Tags: sudo, users, su

I created special user in /etc/passwd with:

```
secure:x:2000:2000:secure:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I don't want to allow login of this user (via console, ssh, ftp, any way).

He is just for running one script via:

```
sudo su secure -c '/home/someuser/secure.script'
```

But it gives me `This user is currently not available.`. How to set it up to be able to run script this way but prevent any login (console, ssh, ftp,...) of this user to system?

---

I have noticed that
when I type `/usr/sbin/nologin` on the command-line, the computer responds with `This account is currently not available.`.

Comment: About `sudo su`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Answer (score 47):

This is a typical use case for `sudo`.

You're mixing `sudo` which allows running commands as another user and is highly configurable (you can selectively specify which user can run which command as which user) and `su` which switches to another user if you know the password (or are root). `su` always runs the shell written in `/etc/passwd`, even if `su -c` is used. Because of this `su` isn't compatible with `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

You should use

`sudo -u secure /home/someuser/secure.script`

As `sudo` is configurable you can control who can use this command and if he/she needs to enter a password to run it. You need to edit `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo` to do this. (Be careful when editing /etc/sudoers and always use visudo to do it. The syntax isn't trivial and one error can lock you out from your root account.)

This line in sudoers allows anyone in group `somegroup` to run the command as `secure`:

```
%somegroup    ALL=(secure) /home/someuser/secure.script
```

This allows anyone in group `somegroup` to run the command as `secure` without entering a password:

```
%somegroup    ALL=(secure) NOPASSWD: /home/someuser/secure.script
```

This allows `user1` to run the command as `secure` without entering a password:

```
user1    ALL=(secure) /home/someuser/secure.script
```

Answer (score 27):

I found out the main problem is "`/usr/sbin/nologin`" in `/etc/passwd`
When I want to execute su in this case, it must have `-s /bin/bash` inside, so for example: `su -s /bin/bash -c '/home/someuser/secure.script' secure`

Comment: Yes, `su` uses the shell written in /etc/passwd by default. Using `su` is a way to login as a user from another user. `nologin` prints the message "This user is currently not available." and exits. `sudo` doesn't use a shell to execute a command, so using `sudo` without `su` will also work. See my answer for more about `sudo`.

Answer (score 6):

`su` is using the shell specified in `/etc/passwd`.

You don't need to use `su` with `sudo`.

Therefore don't mix `su` with `sudo`: use `sudo -u secure '/home/someuser/secure.script'`.