# Does "sudo su" makes me the root user?

Tags: sudo, root, su

I have typed `sudo su` in the Terminal, and then I typed `whoami`, and the Terminal said that I am the root user. So does that mean that `sudo su` makes me the root user or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have the answer in `man su`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   su [options...] [-] [user [args...]]

DESCRIPTION
   su allows to run commands with substitute user and group ID.

   When called without arguments su defaults to running an interactive shell as root.
```

Note that the recommended method to do so is `sudo su -`, as it starts the root shell with a login shell environment:

```
   -, -l, --login
          Starts the shell as login shell with an environment similar to a real login:

             o      clears all environment variables except for TERM

             o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, PATH

             o      changes to the target user's home directory

             o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell
```

or directly run `sudo -i` as explained [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su).