# Account's password won't let me sudo

Tags: sudo

I want my server to not allow root login. For this I want to set the `PermitRootLogin` to `No` (in the SSH daemon config), but before doing that I want to make sure I can switch to root from another user account with `sudo su -`.

The problem is that I reset the password for account admin and then, when I tried to to `sudo su -`, it gives me a message: password incorrect, but the password is the correct one (the new one).

What could be the problem?? I already checked the account is not blocked.

Comment: Welcome to UNIX.stackexchange.com! Your question could use a little clarification. Do you mean you want to deny root login via SSH (I assume so because PermitRootLogin is the parameter name in sshd_config). You say you reset the password for account 'admin'...is this a regular user account you created? When you changed the 'admin' account password, did you start a new terminal/session and try to use sudo in the new session?

Comment: Use `sudo su -`

Comment: @AlexP See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes I know. It was an attempt to accomodate OP's desire to use `su -`.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` will ask for the password of the user invoking `sudo`, not for the `root` account password. You also need to make sure that the user using `sudo` is allowed to do so in the `sudoers` file, by either allowing a group that the user is a member of to `sudo`, or by allowing the user directly to `sudo`, with or without entering a password.

On some Linuxes there is a `sudo` group that one may put users into, with a preset config line in the `sudoers` file (possibly commented out by default).

See also "[Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)" for alternatives to the somewhat cumbersome `sudo su -`.