# Login incorrect on Centos 7

Tags: centos, login, su

I can login as any user, but not as a root user in  centos 7. When I type the command `su` and enter password ,it gives me login incorrect message.
What could be the issue?

Comment: have you tried `sudo su -` ? (or `sudo /bin/su -` ), remember, when using sudo you must use password from non root user.

Comment: Try using `sudo su`.

Comment: About `sudo su`, see "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su"

Comment: Thank you.. i did not try "sudo su -" . i will check

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo su`

It will prompt for password.

And you'll enter root mode after that.

Comment: Not `sudo su`. It's either `su -` (root password) or `sudo -i` (user password).