# Executing Alias Command as Another User Fails

Tags: bash, sudo, alias

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

User2 sources a file in it's .bash_profile to set environment specific aliases.

```
# .bash_profile
source $HOME/set_environment_shortcuts
```

Inside $HOME/set_environment_shortcuts (there are many aliases in here).
Example:

```
alias startservices="verylongcommand"
```

Now I would like to 'startservices from another user.

```
[User1@server1 ~]$ sudo su -l User2 -c '. ~/.bash_profile; startservices'
-bash: startservices: command not found
```

The runuser command produces the same result.

```
[User1@Server1 ~]$ sudo runuser -l User2 -c '. ~/.bash_profile; startservices'
-bash: startservices: command not found
```

Do aliases not work in this way?

Note, when bypassing the alias entirely, the command works.

Comment: Is `startservices` defined in the other user's `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: You realize that ``~`` means home directory (as does ``$HOME``), and that different users have different home directories, right?  Please [edit] your question to be a whole lot clearer about what is defined in whose file, and which user is executing which command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Aliases are a shortcut tool for use interactively. For any kind of scripting, use a shell function instead:

```
startservices () {
    # commands go here
}
```

Shell functions are a lot more flexible than aliases in many ways. They are able to take arguments like a shell script does, for starters:

```
startservices () {
    user="$1"
    service="$2"
    # code to start service "$service" as user "$user"
}
```

---

You should not have to source the other user's `.bash_profile` explicitly.  Use `sudo -i` instead.  This will start a login shell, which will read `.bash_profile` when starting:

```
$ sudo -i -u User2 startservices
```

This requires `startservices` to either be a script or other external utility in the `$PATH` of `User2`, a shell function defined in the shell startup files of `User2`, or an alias (with the shell running with `expand_aliases` set) defined in the shell startup files of `User2`.

See also [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll need to rebuild the script that sets the alias, to instead set functions. I will test using functions shortly. As for "sudo -i".  It creates a different problem. I tried it earlier and the command prompts User1 for a password even though the user is a sudoer.

Comment: So I ended up using expand_aliases. It seems to be a cleaner approach than rebuilding the entire script. The script sets aliases based on three factors, user/host/environment. Within the alias there are variables that pick up strings based on those factors as well. Assigning the aliases to a function that applies to many user environments made most sense with my knowledge of scripting.

Is  shopt -s expand_aliases considered acceptable use, and not really a band-aid approach? What are the pros/cons to this?

Comment: @Motorahead I would honestly do a function for this, it sounds like a lot of logic and parameters could be built into the function, which would make it self-contained. I'm guessing you now have a lot of logic tests that sets of some variation of the alias based on the environment. This logic could be moved into the function.

Comment: Yeah there a bunch of logic tests that determine which function to call, thus setting the aliases. I'll have to look at containing that logic into a function as you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The alias is defined in user1's .bash_profile .
When you use "su -l user2" it actually clears all the environment variables for user1 and loads user2's variables instead, where no "startservices' alias is defined.

You can use "su -p " option which will preserve the current environment, but in that case user2 has to have read permission on user1's .bashrc file.

Comment: Sorry no, the aliases are defined in User2.