# proceed execution of script after change user

Tags: shell-script, sudo, su

I want to continue the execution of the script after change user, the script would be something like below

> echo "xauth add" `xauth list | grep ${DISPLAY:10:2}` >> test.sh
>
> sudo su
>
> ./test.sh

script test.sh should be run after changing the user, but after "sudo su", the command ./test.sh wouldn't run. Can we make this possible

Answer (score 3):

You can not change user identity in the middle of a script and then continue running the script as that new user.

You may however execute another command or script as another user using `sudo`:

```
sudo ./test.sh
```

If more than one command needs to be run as the other user, then add these commands to the `test.sh` script, or, if it's just one or two more things that needs to be run, use

```
sudo sh -c './test.sh; other_command'
```

Control will be handed back to the parent script (the one calling `sudo`) as soon as whatever `sudo` is executing has terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the user mid-script, but this requires feeding the input to the shell and may not be portable to old and eldritch flavors of `sh`) and is probably a bad idea:

```
$ cat changemidscript
who am i
sudo -i
who am i
$ bash < changemidscript
jhqdoe   tty??    Oct  5 14:21 
root     tty??    Oct  5 14:21 
$
```

However! `bash changemidscript` or `./changemidscript` will both not behave the same as the above, which again points to this being a bad idea, as only the feed-the-input-in-via-standard-input will allow the user change and then the subsequent commands as that new user. (Did I mention you probably want to use a different way? You should!)

`strace` may help show why this method works; shells may take pains to read the input line by line, so will either read in one character increments (so they can stop reading when a `\n` is found) or will read into a buffer and then back the file handle up to the beginning of the next line for each line, depending on where the `\n` are found.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the shell executing that last line of the script is the shell started by `sudo -i`, not the shell originally executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually, you want to do either `sudo su -l -c ./test.sh` (if you need a login shell) or `sudo ./test.sh`.

Look at the man pages for `su` and `sudo`.

Comment: Or just `sudo ./test.sh`? Why su to root from root(sudo)?

Comment: Aieee.. Please don't continue the cargo cult construct `sudo su`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su

Comment: @jeff Schaller yes, "sudo su -c ./test.sh". is running the above command in root but not changing to root user. I want to change to root user because some more set of commands that need to be executed

Comment: @roaima I read the related forum, thank's for sharing I will change the script little built