# Command not found when run as sudo

Tags: sudo, path, puppet

I'm running centos7. I installed puppet. if I write `puppet` as a user, I get a proper output. If I write `sudo puppet` I get `command not found`.

The really weird thing is, if I do `sudo su -` and become root, then write `puppet`, I get the normal output that I get when I run it with the normal user...

```
[unu@centosmaster puppet]$ puppet
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands
[unu@centosmaster puppet]$ sudo puppet
sudo: puppet: command not found
[unu@centosmaster puppet]$ sudo su -
Last login: Wed Sep 19 08:41:20 EDT 2018 on pts/0
[root@centosmaster ~]# puppet
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands
```

This, to me, makes absolutely no sense...

The `$PATH` variable is the same for root and normal user.

Comment: [There's no point in using `sudo su -`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222). Either just use `su -` or, if you don't have the root password, use `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/548508/why-cant-i-sudo-some-commands-e-g-vim) on Super User site, CentOS sanitizes the enviromnent to a sane default.

That's why some commands won't work with `sudo`.

Looks like you should check in `/etc/sudoers` (edit it with `visudo` !!) for these options:

```
Defaults env_reset 
Defaults env_keep += "SOME_VARIABLE_NAME" # There should be one or more of these
```

This line:

```
Defaults    secure_path = "some path"
```

specifically overrides your user's `$PATH` with a predetermined one which
evidently differs from what you're expecting.

You might want to modify `secure_path` to your needs, or just comment the whole line if you feel your standard user's `$PATH` should be used even with `sudo [command]`.