# sudo execute as other user with parameters

Tags: sudo, arguments

I created a (system) user, eg: `mysysuser`, and some sudo rules so it can do some maintenance in other users folders.

This script needs to run as other user but also needs some parameters.

Therefore, I created the following in `/etc/sudoers.d/mysysuser`

example:

```
Cmnd_Alias FIRST = /usr/bin/su -l user1 -c '/home/*/www/*/deploy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2"' * * *
Cmnd_Alias SECOND = /usr/bin/su -l user2 -c '/home/*/www/*/deploy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2"' * * *
mysysuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: FIRST,SECOND
```

Then I run:

```
sudo /usr/bin/su -l user1 -c '/home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh' "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"
```

this does not work and asks for password.

This version without parameters works fine and executes without asking password:

```
Cmnd_Alias FIRST = /usr/bin/su -l user1 -c /home/*/www/*/deploy.sh * * *
```

But... the script does not receive the args.

I know the sudoers file needs it to be very literal with the exception for the wildcard:*

I am wondering why it does not work, is it the:

> "$0" "$1" "$2"

part?

Escaping the dollar signs makes `visudo` barf.

UPDATE:

As per the comments, it is advised to use sudo directly without the su command.

I tried this but now I can't get it to work, sudo asks for the password although it shouldn't.

/etc/sudoers.d/mysysuser:

```
Cmnd_Alias FIRST = /home/*/www/*/deploy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2" * * *
mysysuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: FIRST
```

the command I execute as mysysuser:

```
sudo -u user1 /home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"
```

result:

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> ```
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
> #2) Think before you type.
> #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
> ```
>
> [sudo] password for mysysuser:

Comment: When you run `sudo su ...` you are in effect saying, "Hello `sudo` please can I have root access ... thank you. Hello `su`, although I'm already root please would you give me root access ... thank you`.

Answer (score 0):

To run `sudo` you have to run `sudo`:

Therefore your command MUST start with `sudo`.

Also you never need to use `su` in conjunction with `sudo`. `sudo` can handle users and groups. You can configure who can run what as who.

Comment: yes, i left out sudo, the full command is:
sudo /usr/bin/su -l user1 -c '/home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh' "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"
(sorry, i thought that was clear, my bad)

Comment: i want to use sudo so i can specify the allowed commands very specifically. i only want the mysysuser to run one specific command and nothing else.

Comment: .. and it needs to run in the environment of the 'other' user

Comment: @chichi as ctrl-alt-delor said, [you don't need su](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222). Just run `sudo -u user1 home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"`.

Comment: @terdon, if i do that it keeps asking for the password as to when i use the su part it doesnt.

sudoers: Cmnd_Alias FIRST = /home/*/www/*/deploy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2" * * *

command: sudo -u user1 /home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"

any ideas?

Comment: @chichi please put updates in the question: so they are in one place, and formatted so we can read them.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor ok, I updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

nevermind, it works fine without the single quotes in the sudoers file:

```
Cmnd_Alias FIRST = /usr/bin/su -l user1 -c /home/*/www/*/deploy.sh "$0" "$1" "$2" * * *
```

with this command:

```
/usr/bin/su -l user1 -c '/home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh' "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"
```

Comment: How does editing `/etc/sudoers`, help with running `su`?

Comment: sorry i left out sudo in the example, the full command is ofcourse: 
sudo /usr/bin/su -l user1 -c '/home/user1/www/site1/deploy.sh' "param 1" "param 2" "param 3"

Comment: Please edit the question, to show what you did. Paste the real code, not an impression of it.