# How can I get root permissions with running "sudo su -" instead of "/tools/xgs/bin/sudo su -"?

Tags: bash, sudo, root

Currently I am running a server on vnc with RHEL 7 operating system.

Background:

1. I login to the server say `kpod@server1`
2. Now when I need to access root permissions. I use the path `/tools/xgs/bin/sudo su -`
3. Instead of the full path, how can I get root access with only running command `sudo`?

Note:

- `/etc/` contains - `sudoers.rpmsave`
- `/etc/` doesn't contain `sudoers.d`

How can I become `root` with running only `sudo`?

Edit: /tools/xgs/bin/sudo is the path where the `sudo`package is stored.

Comment: Is `server1` really RHEL or is it Solaris?

Comment: Do you need a `sudo` binary in the existing path? Or is this just about the user you log in as? You could define an alias in the user's shell config or change `PATH` for that user.

Comment: You could also use `sudo -s` (or `sudo -i`, I suppose) instead of this horrible `sudo su` malarky

Comment: @roaima- When I do "cat /etc/os-release"- I get the below output:

NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation"
VERSION="7.4 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Workstation"
VARIANT_ID="workstation"
VERSION_ID="7.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 7.4 (Maipo)"

Comment: @roaima- "sudo " is present in the path /tools/xgs/bin/sudo.

sudo : command not found if I try "sudo -s".

Comment: @HaukeLaging - It is for all users. 
I tried using alias for user shell but the sudo command is not recognized by the shell.

Comment: What is there to be recognized? If you do `alias sudo=/tools/xgs/bin/sudo` and then `sudo -s` that "has to work".

Comment: @HaukeLaging-
Doesn't works.
1. edited the .user.sh file 
2. alias sudo=/tools/xgs/bin/sudo
3. trying to login:
 #sudo -s
bash: sudo: command not found...

Comment: @K-pod Add that alias to your `~/.bashrc` file. Log out, then log in, then use `sudo`.

Comment: You can execute `alias sudo=/tools/xgs/bin/sudo` in the running shell. No need for putting it in a config file in the first step. Usually you want to know whether it works before you put it in a config file.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this sort of thing:

1. Add a simple alias to your `~/.bashrc` file (or wherever you usually define aliases):

   ```
   alias sudo=/tools/xgs/bin/sudo
   ```

   Then log out and log in again (or at least open a new terminal).  The alias should then be active.
2. Modify your `PATH` variable (possibly also in `~/.bashrc`) by appending the path where the `sudo` command lives:

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/tools/xgs/bin
   ```

   This would additionally give you access to all other executables at that path.  The same thing applies here, log out and in again, or at least open a new terminal.

For testing either of these variations before you add them to your shell's startup file, you could just give either of the above commands in an interactive shell.

Also note that `sudo su` is never really necessary. See e.g. "[Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)"