# Environment Variable and PATH issue

Tags: bash, kali-linux, root, path

I tried to set an environment variable for the `Sublist3r` tool and messed up. Now whenever I switch to the `root` user (with `sudo su`) the only command I am able to use is `exit` (attaching the images).

I tried to edit `/root/.bashrc` but it seems to be fine on non-root user account. I also checked the `PATH` on root account which it is showing as 'sublister-1'. How can I edit `/root/.bashrc`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the normal user:

```
sudo /bin/nano /root/.bashrc
```

And please don't `sudo su`, you can use `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` to get elevated shells (see the Q/A [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo su` is perfectly okay depending on use cases, as of "missing" commands, utilities is still there, you just need to use full paths to access them.

```
/usr/bin/nano
/usr/bin/vim
```

and so on, fix your `$PATH` and it should be back to normal

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot :)