# SUDO_* environment variables not set when using sudo su -

Tags: sudo, su

I have a use case where I want to `sudo su - user1` to some user and then run script and in the script I want to fetch `SUDO_USER`. However the `SUDO_*` environment variables do not get set when I use `sudo su - user1` instead of `sudo su app`.

```
sudo su user1
[sudo] password for rbhanot:
$ env | grep -i sudo
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su user1
SUDO_GID=4361
SUDO_UID=4361
SUDO_USER=rbhanot
```

If I invoke `su` with login shell these variables are not set

```
sudo su - user1
$ env|grep -i sudo
$
```

It works if I use a slightly different command with `sudo -i`

```
sudo -i -u user1
$ env|grep -i sudo
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/ksh
SUDO_GID=4361
SUDO_UID=4361
SUDO_USER=rbhanot
```

So why does these `SUDO_*` variables do not get with `su - user1` specifically.

Comment: haven't read the code, but the manpage says the optional `-` is to "provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly" and i wouldn't expect those variables to be set on a direct login

Comment: Related: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169)

Comment: @Kusalananda I know but still people use these interchangebly and hence the expected behaviour is different than actual one.

Comment: Then they may want to change their expectation, or their behavior. For example, in this case you may want to use `sudo -i` instead, or not rely on those variables being set.  Or, you could change your question to not be about `sudo` at all and ask why `su -` clears the environment.

Comment: `sudo su` Considered Harmful. Read `man sudo sudoers su`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the -i and the variables should go across for you.

If that doesn't work, you might consider having them specify the variables on the command line?  Maybe not ideal, but it would give the users the flexibility you want..

```
ie.  sudo -i -u joe SUDO_GID=4361 SUDO_UID=4361 SUDO_USER=rbhanot /bin/ksh
```

If that's a bit much for the users to remember, you can add an alias for it in their .bash_profile.

```
ie.  alias myroot="sudo -i -u joe SUDO_GID=4361 SUDO_UID=4361 SUDO_USER=rbhanot /bin/ksh"
```

Then they simply type "myroot" and it will run the sudo command as written.