# SSH to machine and change user to root

Tags: ssh

I am trying to SSH a remote machine and change user to root and run a series of command which need root

I tried the command below but seems it's not working

```
sshpass -p <pwd> ssh -q  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null <user>@$IP "echo <pwd>| sudo -S su; whoami"
```

`whoami` always return  instead of root

Any idea how to get it done?

edit

`echo <pwd> | sudo -S <some-command>` always work in this case, but not with `sudo -S su` ?

Comment: You are running `echo <pwd>| sudo -S su;` (which fails, try it on your local machine) and then `whoami` as a separate command, so that will never return `root`. What command do you _really_ need to run as root on the remote machine? Since you have root access on the remote, can't you configure `sudo` to allow your user to run that command with `sudo` without a password? Would that be an acceptable solution? Also, since you don't seem to be very concerned about security, can you configure the remote to allow root login?

Comment: @terdon this CMD has to be run in multiple / random test machine, which allowing root login or disable sudo's password is not feasible

Comment: @terdon is not talking about disabling passwords, but about allowing your user to run specific binaries as root without having to supply a password to `sudo`.

Comment: Can you use ansible?

Comment: @Panki as mentioned, the cmd is targeted to a large number of test machines, i prefer one line command instead of configuring each of the machine beforehand

Comment: The entire point of `sudo` is to run a command as root. [It doesn't make sense](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/) to run `sudo su` in any case, but here it makes even less sense. Why don't you just run `ssh ... sudo -S command` ?

Comment: @JeffPang if that's your preference, you'd best get used to typing in the password . You'll be doing it a lot.  Otherwise, you'll need to either or both of: 1. configure sudo to allow your user to run certain commands as root without a password, or 2. install .authorized_keys for root allowing certain keys to either get a login shell or to to run particular commands/scripts, or both.   There are several questions & answers on this site detailing how to do all of those things.