# What are difference between -bash and bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, login

When I log in as `root` and enter some random non-existing command, it says:

```
root@localhost:~# asdf
-bash: asdf: command not found
root@localhost:~#
```

But when I do the same thing as user `rakinar2` it says:

```
rakinar2@localhost:~$ asdf
bash: asdf: command not found
rakinar2@localhost:~$
```

Now what are difference between -bash and bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash started with a dash `-` as the first character for the command name (argument #0) starts as a login shell. (So does a shell given the `-l` / `--login` switch.) That affects the startup files it reads.

See: [6.1 Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) and [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) in the manual.

Comment: @ArRakin, if a login or non-login shell is started depends on what starts it. I don't know how you logged in as root, but if you're using `sudo`, `sudo -i` would start a login shell. Terminal emulators and stuff like `screen` usually probably start non-login shells, unless you've configured them to start login shells...

Comment: I've used `sudo su` to log in as root...

Comment: @ArRakin See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169