# how to set environment vars (PS1) when using su - user

Tags: bash

Working on Ubuntu (but I doubt it matters).

Our Unix servers are set up so users (read admins) have to login to their personal accounts.  If you need to work as an other (say application user) you `sudo su - elasticsearch` for example.

I want to be able to customise the prompt for these accounts but adding a .bashrc file and setting `$PS1` does not have any affect.

It is unclear to me just what `su` does when one specifies `-`.  The man page is vague "Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly."

I need a pointer to some docs that explain which profile/rc files get processed in this case.

Comment: Tangentially related: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169)

Comment: These accounts have no passwords and can not be logged into normally

Answer (score 0):

You start a login shell by issuing `su -`, and the file that is executed/sourced is `.bash_profile`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html