# sudo not preserving PATH

Tags: sudo, path

I have a strange issue where `sudo` is not preserving the PATH by default. I tried the answers from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path) and it works when I use the `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"` version but I want to fix this permanently.

Here's my PATH as regular user and under sudo:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk/bin:/opt/python3/bin:/opt/qt5/bin
$ sudo printenv | grep 'PATH'
PATH=/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc
```

I tried `sudo -E` and `sudo "PATH=$PATH` but they don't work either. `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"` works but I have to type it every time run `sudo`. I want to avoid doing that every time I run `sudo`.

I'm not sure where `sudo` is picking up this path from. I don't have `secure_path` hard-coded or `env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers`. Hence this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path).

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix this? I would prefer not create aliases or hard-code the `secure_path`.

#### Edit:

As requested, the output of `sudo -l`:

```
$ sudo -l
User munir may run the following commands on munir-lfs:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: What does `sudo -l` report?

Comment: @muru Added that to the question

Comment: @ThomasDickey I have already seen that question and it is linked in the first paragraph of my question but it is not a permanent solution. Like I have already mentioned in the question, I want this to be fixed without having to do `sudo env "PATH=$PATH`. Basically I want the PATH under sudo to be the same as the users PATH, always.

Comment: There's more than one solution offered there, some are permanent.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I tried all...none of them worked. I wouldn't be asking this question otherwise. I don't want to hard-code the `secure_path` unless as a last resort.

Comment: @Munir it would be a security hole to preserve the `PATH`. You can overwrite it (with `secure_path`) but you shouldn't really be looking to preserve it.

Comment: @roaima I am the only user on the system, and it is really irritating that software I have installed under `/usr/local/bin` and `/opt` doesn't work because `sudo` can't find it. My current PATH without `sudo` is the system PATH from `/etc/profile`. So, it is really surprising that `sudo` is not using that but creating it's own PATH.

Comment: @Munir remove the `secure_path` definition and then check `sudo -V`. On my system here this preserves `PATH` (and can be verified as doing so).

Comment: @roaima I don't have a `secure_path` defined, which is why I am confused that the PATH is different under `sudo`. My current `/etc/sudoers` has only two lines which are not commented out: `root ALL=(ALL) ALL %sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Which section does `sudo -V` have `PATH` listed in?

Comment: You can get more info on sudo's builtin config from `sudo sudo -V`. You might try adding a sudoers entry to override any builtin options: `Defaults:munir  !secure_path, env_keep+="PATH"`. Make sure you have a root shell somewhere to reover with first.

Comment: @roaima PATH is under Environment variables to preserve. I guess I'll just define a `secure_path` since this question has been (incorrectly) closed.

Comment: @Munir it's on its way to being reopened. (Slowly.) If I get to write an answer I'll see if I can determine the necessary settings to allow `PATH` to carry through. I achieved it on my test system here so it's clearly possible.

Comment: @roaima Thanks...i defined a `secure_path` and it works as expected. But if you have an alternate would be interested in knowing it. Let's wait for this to reopen.

Comment: @roaima post is reopened