# Why is my sudo PATH different than my normal user PATH?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, path, profile

I'm having trouble with my PATH.  I have a clean instance of an Amazon Linux virtual server and I set this in /etc/profile

```
M3_HOME=/usr/local/maven
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
PATH="$PATH:$M3_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

In my myuser (my own user) account, I set this in my ~/.bash_profile

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

And then when I output the "env" as my user I get

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/home/myuser/bin
```

But when I output it as sudo I get

```
sudo env
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

How do I get my sudo user to use the same path as my normal user?

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/257802

Answer (score 2):

Because when you execute sudo you are promoted to root, a different user with a different environment.

You can maintain the same environment variables with --preserve-env option.

This was lifted straight from the man page for sudo and checked on my Linux box under bash. The following give the same output

```
env | grep PATH

sudo --preserve-env=PATH env | grep PATH
```

Check your man page.

Comment: I'm not clear on how to solve my problem given what you list here.  Entering "su - " does not change the PATH var of sudo.

Comment: I misread the linked post but just rechecked the sudo man page.

Comment: I think I have been looking for this AGES. If I run `sudo --preserve-env=PATH env` the `$PATH` of the user inking `sudo` is preserved. Thanks!