# Why do the following ways to preserve environment variables for sudo not work?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400598/156458

> The other solutions I've seen here so far are based on some system
>   definitions, but it's in fact possible to have `sudo` use the current
>   `PATH` (with the `env` command) and/or the rest of the environment
>   (with the `-E` option) just by invoking it right:
>
> ```
> sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]
> ```
>
> In fact, one can make an alias out of it:
>
> ```
> alias mysudo='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'
> ```
>
> (It's also possible to name the alias itself `sudo`, replacing the
>   original `sudo`.)

Given that

> -E, --preserve-env
>   Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy
>   may return an error if the user
>                    does not have permission to preserve the environment.

I was wondering why the following doesn't work

```
sudo -E <command> [arguments]
```

?

Given that `"PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]` is also a command, I was wondering why the following doesn't work:

```
sudo  "PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make \`sudo\` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I haven't voted, but I could imagine a reader asking "What do you mean by `doesn't work`?" - Does sudo fail? Does the command not get the updated environment? Does it not match a sudoers entry?  I think it'd also be useful to include the sudo configuration here regarding whitelist/blacklist/keep settings.

Comment: Your statement, "_Given that `"PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]` is also a command..._" is a false premise. It's not a command; it's an environment variable assignment followed by a command. Quoting aside, you could try `sudo bash -c "PATH=... command args..."`. Just bear in mind that `command` would still need to be in your default `sudo`  value of `$PATH` or else you'd need to use an explicit `/path/to/command`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo -E <command> [arguments]
```

doesn’t work in your case because Debian defines `secure_path` in `/etc/defaults`, which overrides the value of `PATH` even with `-E`.

```
sudo  "PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]
```

should work because `PATH=$PATH` is recognised and processed by `sudo`. In my case `sudo "PATH=$PATH" env` shows my current `PATH` value. (Note that `PATH=$PATH <command>` isn’t a universally-recognised command; it corresponds to a construct which is recognised by the shell and by `sudo`, but not necessarily in other contexts.).

However `sudo` itself doesn't use that `$PATH` to look the `<command>` up and still uses the `secure_path`.

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]
```

works because `"PATH=$PATH"` stores the current value of `PATH` in the command as seen by `sudo` and then `env`; `sudo` replaces the value of `PATH` as given to `env` in its environment, but `env` then reads the value from its arguments to build the environment for `<command>`.

And here, the `env` command is looked-up by `sudo` in `secure_path`, but `env` itself looks `<command>` up in the provided `$PATH`.

Comment: `sudo --preserve-env=PATH` is better than `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"` (I used `--preserve-env` instead of `-E`, because I prefer long options for readability when I write scripts; it is the same option)

Comment: @artyom.razinov here, `-E` isn’t usable, as explained in the first paragraph. Redefining `PATH` is a workaround — it’s handled by `env`, not `sudo`, and as a result avoids the `PATH` restrictions imposed by `sudo`. (I can’t remember why I wrote `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"`; the effect should be the same with `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"`.)

Comment: `sudo --preserve-env=PATH` still seems better than `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"`. First, it's the option of sudo, second, you don't need shell interpreter for this, this is just an argument and not a literal with code in sh/bash/zsh like `$PATH`. Also if you use something like `ssh ... sudo env "PATH=$PATH" ...` you can get unexpected result (`$PATH` will be from a local machine and not from the remote machine). I just wanted to give alternative that I just used in code.

Comment: @artyom.razinov you’re missing the point that `-E` is ignored in the configuration discussed here (because of `secure_path`) — or rather, that `PATH` is set by `sudo` to the value defined by `secure_path`, so the only way to override it is to set it again afterwards (using `env` here).

Comment: You are missing my point. `--preserve-env=PATH` is almost equivalent to `-E /usr/bin/env "PATH=$PATH"` as PATH is not overwritten by `secure_path` in both cases. At least on Mac OS. My point is that I want to provide an alternative that can be better in some cases. For example `PATH=itworks; /usr/bin/sudo -E /usr/bin/env "PATH=$PATH" /usr/bin/printenv PATH` is equivalent to `PATH=itworks; /usr/bin/sudo --preserve-env=PATH /usr/bin/printenv PATH`. However, if you remove `;` it stops being equivalent. Because `$PATH` takes value from current shell and in some cases it can lead to errors.

Comment: @artyom.razinov again, in the context of this question, `-E` isn’t usable, with or without arguments (the OP explicitly mentions that it doesn’t work). If `-E` was usable, then yes, `-E` is preferable, but that isn’t the case here (and that’s the entire premise of the question — if `-E` did work, there would be no question).