# Why running command as sudo returns command not found?

Tags: sudo, path

Sample command:

```
drush cc all
```

works, but this:

```
sudo drush cc all
```

gives me:

```
sudo: drush: command not found
```

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: I've also had this issue sometimes, with such basic commands as `cd`.  Using `dzdo cd` returning "command not found".  Of course I later realized that `cd`ing into a directory that I don't have permissions in, won't help very much, so I either need a root shell or need to `dzdo ls`, `dzdo mv`, etc. the contents from outside that dir.

Comment: The problem with `sudo cd` is that `cd` is a built-in command, not a program. If you want to go into a directory that *you* don't have any access to, and (for example) rename a file there, you could do (for example) `sudo mv dir/oldfile dir/newfile` ***or*** `sudo sh -c "cd dir; mv oldfile newfile"`.

Answer (score 18):

When you `sudo`, you get a preconfigured `$PATH`, which is (supposed to be) something like the **root** user's default path.  Your program is not in that list of directories identified by `$PATH`.

See for example

- [How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path)
- [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su)
- [sudoers(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sudoers.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/sudoers) (see the various settings which relate to `PATH`)
- [sudo(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html)

> **sudo** tries to be safe when executing external commands.
>
> There are two distinct ways to deal with environment variables.  By default, the `env_reset` **sudoers**
>   option is enabled.  This causes commands to be executed with a minimal environment containing **`TERM`**,
>   **`PATH`**, **`HOME`**, **`SHELL`**, **`LOGNAME`**, **`USER`** and **`USERNAME`** in addition to variables from the invoking process
>   permitted by the `env_check` and `env_keep` **sudoers** options.  There is effectively a whitelist for
>   environment variables.

If you cannot configure `sudo` to preserve your `$PATH`, the usual workaround is to specify the complete pathname of the program.  That may not work well with scripts that call other executables in the (not-accessed) directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the full path. It's also more secure; it you don't specify the path, it's conceivable that an attacker could create another program that will be run with root permissions.

Also, you need to put a line in `/etc/sudoers` to allow it. `man sudoers` for the syntax, it's way too much to put here.