# Command not found error - bash

Tags: bash, sudo, root, emacs

```
$ which sudo emacs
  /usr/bin/sudo
  /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs
$ sudo emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
  sudo: emacs: command not found
$ emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf # Works fine
$ which emacs
  /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs
$
```

**Edit:**

I have appended `PATH` for `root` user, just now

```
$ whoami
 user1
$ which emacs
 /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs
$ sudo tail -n 2 -F /root/.bashrc
 #fi
 export PATH=/home/user1/local_build/bin:$PATH
$ 
$ sudo emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
 sudo: emacs: command not found
$
```

**Edit:**

```
# whoami
 root
# command -v emacs
 /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs
# exit
 exit
$ whoami
 user1
$ command -v emacs
 alias emacs='emacs -q --load ~/.emacs.d/init.el'
$
```

**Edit**

```
$ whoami
 user1
$ tail -n 2 -F .bashrc
 alias emacs='emacs -q --load ~/.emacs.d/init.el'

^C
$
```

**Edit:**

After an answer from Tigger, problem still exists,

```
$ tail -n 2 -F /home/user1/.bashrc
# alias emacs='emacs -q --load ~/.emacs.d/init.el'

^C
$ whoami # After logout/login bash
 user1
$ sudo emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
 sudo: emacs: command not found
$
```

**Edit:**

After 7_R3X answer,

```
# whoami
 root
# ls -ltr /etc/sudoers #Unable to modify this file
 -r--r----- 1 root root 755 Oct 14  2016 /etc/sudoers
#
```

BTW, `sudo gedit <etc's filename>` works fine.

**Question:**

Why `emacs` does not get launch using `sudo`?

Comment: Because `/home/user1/local_build/bin` is not on root's `PATH` obviously!

Comment: Try `sudo /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` instead of `sudo emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and comment below the results.

Comment: @7_R3X Uodated query

Comment: @overexchange: I just updated my answer. Please check below. Thanks to steeldriver for sharing his knowledge.

Comment: Why do you have a local install of emacs? And what distribution?

Comment: @FaheemMitha  This approach is needed when you work on build server, where multiple users sitting on that build server can have their own emacs customisation. This hold good for any tool that you use on build server. I would not touch `/usr/bin/emacs` version

Comment: Isn't customization what `.emacs` is for? Did you want a more recent version than the one installed on the machine?

Comment: @FaheemMitha  Some customisations  in `.emacs` need newer version of `emacs`

Answer (score 4):

<strike>cylgalad has mentioned the reason for your error in the comment that the path `/home/user1/local_build/bin` is not present in root's system variable `PATH`.</strike>

The reason of your problem is that the directory `/home/user1/local_build/bin` is not present in variable `secure_path`. To add this directory in `secure_path`, you need to edit `/etc/sudoers` file and change the content in it's Defaults content.

OR alternatively,

To solve the problem, you could either run emacs by explicitly mentioning it's full path in the command:

`sudo /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

<strike>or alternatively</strike>

you could add the path `/home/user1/local_build/bin/` to root's `PATH`. Just put the folliwing line in your `.bashrc` file located at `~/root/` directory.

`PATH=$PATH:~/home/user1/local_build/bin`

Adding directory to root's `PATH` won't work for the reasons mentioned by steeldriver in the comment.

Comment: `sudo` is usually configured to use its own `secure_path` rather that root's `PATH` - see for example [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8652/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver : Oops! I didn't know that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: 1) your first line is contradicting with last line in the answer. 2) How to set `sudo`'s `secure_path`?

Comment: @overexchange: Forgot to edit it. Hold on a second.

Comment: Sorry, why `sudo` has its own `/etc/sudoers`'s `secure_path` instead of relying on `/root/.bashrc`'s `PATH` variable? What is the reason to maintain `secure_path` in addition to `root`'s `PATH` variable? Is `sudo`'s version of executing command(`emacs`) does not mean to seek `root` privilege access to execute the command as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80350/62659)? BTW, am yet to verify your suggestion

Comment: Query edited, after following your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Classic example of [why to not use `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/85250).

At the core of the issue is `which`. If you check what `type emacs` or `command -v emacs` says then your problem would be solved.

Edit:
If you are trying to run as the `root` user, what happens when you try:

```
su
<password>
command -v emacs
```

Edit 2: That `alias` is the issue. You need to check `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` for that user. Either amended it or create a new `alias` would be my suggestion.

**Edit 3:** You are doing non-standard stuff, that is installing `emacs` in a users folder, then expecting to be able to execute it as `root`. This means you need a non-standard solution.

**Option 1**

Install `emacs` to `/usr/local/bin` - the correct location. Do not use a users folder to store applications you expect to be accessible to `root`.

**Option 2**

Use the full path when running `emacs` - as pointed out in the answer by 7_R3X. For example:

```
sudo /home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs
```

**Option 3**

Add the following `alias`:

```
alias emacs='/home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs'
```

This `alias` should be added to both `/home/user1/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc`. If `/root/.bashrc` does not exist, just create it.

Option 3 is not recommended (in my opinion) as it it starting to create a real mess of your system. It is also possible that `root` does not use the `bash` shell. I don't know why you have `emacs` in the users folder, so I have included this option.

Another option is to change the `alias` for Option 3 to something more custom like:

```
alias emacsuser1='/home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs'
```

or even

```
alias localemacs='/home/user1/local_build/bin/emacs'
```

This way you know you are running a non-standard install or custom version.

Comment: Query updated, after this answer

Comment: `alias` coming from `/home/user1/.bashrc`

Comment: After commenting it out, I get the path for `emacs`

Comment: Edited query, problem still exists. Why commenting `alias` suppose to work?

Comment: @overexchange See edit 3 for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to get an idea of what's going on by stracing the execution of Emacs (sudo). [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/) is a nice and friendly explanation on how to use it.