# PATH env var declared in /etc/environment not inherited?

Tags: environment-variables, path

Working on `Ubuntu 16.04.05`.

According to the official [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables) and [ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment) documentations, variables declared therein should be inherited by all users;

Then how is the following explained:

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
root@pkara-pc01:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

(i.e. paths in `/etc/environment` not ending up in `root` `PATH`) given that no explicit `PATH` override seems to take place in:

a) `/root/.profile`

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# grep -i path /root/.profile
root@pkara-pc01:~#
```

b) `/root/.bashrc`

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# grep -i path /root/.bashrc
root@pkara-pc01:~#
```

c) `/etc/profile`

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# grep -i path /etc/profile
root@pkara-pc01:~#
```

d) in `/etc/profile.d/` there is only a `PATH` expansion to account for `/snap/bin`

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# grep -rniI -A 1 path /etc/profile.d/
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:3:# Expand $PATH to include the directory where snappy applications go.
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:4:if [ "${PATH#*/snap/bin}" = "${PATH}" ]; then
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:5:    export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh-6-fi
```

**Update**:

Regarding relation to [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su) as pointed out by @Kusalandra,

```
$ su -
Password: 
root@pkara-pc01:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
root@pkara-pc01:~# exit
logout
/home/pkara/Workspace/gitlab/sonar-scanner
$ sudo -i
root@pkara-pc01:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
root@pkara-pc01:~#
```

However:

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# grep -i secure_path /etc/sudoers
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

So it seems the `secure_path` is applied in **both** `su` and `sudo` cases? (which is **not** what the related issue states).

Comment: How do you log in as root?

Comment: Did a `sudo -i`

Comment: `sudo` may well set the `PATH` for root to some predetermined value or there may be some other security policy in place that changes the `PATH` from what's in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: This may be closely related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su

Comment: @Kusalananda pls check my update on the topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default paths come from `/etc/login.defs`, which contains (in Debian at least, I suspect it’s the same in Ubuntu):

```
#
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
#
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

This is mentioned at the bottom of [the Debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables) you linked to, in the context of `su`.

Comment: I modified `ENV_SUPATH` in Ubuntu 22.04, but `sudo -s` still shows an unmodified `$PATH`, any idea why?

Comment: @bilogic `login.defs` is only taken into account for logins, you need to use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo -s`.

Comment: there is yet another location, `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`, modifying it did the trick

Comment: @bilogic yes, that’s mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks, finally saw it, I missed it when looking from a) to d)