# Sudo echo path does not show the path that is used to execute as sudo

Tags: sudo, path

I'm confused by the following:

```
[user@QVr740-11 ~]$ which ninja
/usr/local/bin/ninja
[user@QVr740-11 ~]$ sudo which ninja
which: no ninja in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
[user@QVr740-11 ~]$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
```

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/ninja` shows that the binary is owned by root:root, and executable by all (three x's), and `$PATH` shows that even as sudo, it should be in the path, however when I go to execute `which`, the path has somehow changed.

`sudo -E` does not change this behaviour.

What gives? Is $PATH being preserved? Is `which` looking elsewhere for a path (note that I can't execute this binary as sudo).

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here

1. The `$PATH` variable is being expanded before the command is run. The net result is that you get this, which while being valid isn't really what you're wanting:

   ```
   sudo echo /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
   ```
2. The `$PATH` is usually reset by `sudo` for security reasons

You could use `sudo env | grep ^PATH=` to find the `$PATH` value in the context of `sudo` running an application.  You can adjust the path in `/etc/sudoers` - use `sudo visudo` to edit this file so that you get the benefit of a syntax check *before* you change the file.

Answer (score -1):

Read `man sudo sudoers`. `sudo` commands intentionally ignore the user's `$PATH`, to avoid an easy security breach.

Comment: Interesting caveat - the run process sees the user's $PATH, but that process is run based on a search in root's $PATH.

Comment: the run process does not see the users `$PATH`. That variable is expanded by the shell before being handed off to sudo.

Comment: This could be improved with a demonstration that `sudo echo $PATH` has expanded $PATH before even calling `sudo`.

Comment: The actual setting of secure_path (and/or env_reset) would add value as well.