# How to keep all environmental variables during sudo?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

I am trying to use `sudo -u postgres` to run all postgresql commands inside a container and I'd like to inherit all environment variables before the `sudo`.

I need to `sudo` in the first place because some of postgres cannot be run as root:

```
root@473f05e08ea1:/# pg_ctl
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
```

Hence the use of `sudo -u postgres` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312590/4196578). The first issue encountered is that `PATH` env variables are different after sudo, and postgres commands cannot be found:

```
root@473f05e08ea1:/# sudo -u postgres pg_ctl
sudo: pg_ctl: command not found
```

After some search, one can use [-E option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400598/4196578) to inherit `PATH`:

```
root@473f05e08ea1:/# sudo -u postgres -E env "PATH=$PATH" pg_ctl
pg_ctl: no operation specified
```

This makes me wonder:

*Is there a way to inherit ALL environment variables (including `PGDATA`, `PGOPTIONS`, `HOME` etc. etc.)? Or do I have to inherit them one by one via trial-and-errors?*

**Related:**

[Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646)

-- Update --

The output of `diff -u <(sudo -E env) <(env)` is:

```
root@2f8a4b93e1da:/# diff -u <(sudo -E env) <(env)
--- /dev/fd/63  2023-03-18 20:36:44.898156660 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2023-03-18 20:36:44.898156660 +0000
@@ -8,12 +8,5 @@
 TERM=xterm
 SHLVL=1
 PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
-PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
-_=/usr/bin/sudo
-LOGNAME=root
-USER=root
-SHELL=/bin/bash
-SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
-SUDO_USER=root
-SUDO_UID=0
-SUDO_GID=0
+PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin
+_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: @Quasímodo Please see the update I just added.

Comment: The command `pg_ctl` as `postgres` is functioning as it should. You simply haven't specified an option for it as is indicated by the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your second command,

```
sudo -u postgres -E env "PATH=$PATH" pg_ctl
```

is functioning as it should.

You simply haven't specified an option for the command `pg_ctl` as is indicated by the error message.

To clarify this, if you

```
su -l postgres
```

and then run the command

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/pg_ctl
```

or

```
su -l postgres
```

and then

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin:$PATH
```

followed by

```
pg_ctl
```

you'll get the same error for the same reason.

See the man page of `pg_ctl` for available options during use.