# Why is it safer to give sudo rights to a non root user?

Tags: security, sudo

I have recently installed Amazon Linux on EC2 to run NodeJS applications.

It is recommended to run them as a non root user. This user will still be me so there is no concern that someone else will have access to vim, that's off the list.

I added a newuser and now newuser has the same sudo rights as root. So how is it safer now? Is it just because newuser will have to enter a password to run commands?

[Set up a NodeJS production environment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

Answer (score 6):

Because you can define a specific set of commands in `/etc/sudoers` that newuser is limited to running with elevated privileges. Ideally you find out what minimum commands are needed and limit it to that. Don't allow the account to sudo all commands as root if you can help it.

Next, you do not permit root to login via ssh. (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set `PermitRootLogin no`). You always ssh login as yourself, not root, then just use sudo as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If a malicious user got access to your login and you have unrestricted `sudo` access, you are correct: `sudo` access wouldn't provide any additional barrier compared to just using a `root` shell directly.  (That's likely the first thing they would do with their `sudo` access anyway.)

However, if it's just *you* using it, using normal privileges except when you actually *need* root access can help prevent some unpleasant mistakes.

**It's not a point of security; it's a point of accident prevention.**

This has been discussed extensively elsewhere on this site:

- [Why do I have to use sudo for almost everything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/237221/135943)

---

Note: Setting up `sudo` in a corporate environment with access restricted to very specific commands is of course an actual security advantage.  With my statement above I'm referring to personal computers, and answering the question: *"Why is unrestricted `sudo` access preferable to using a `root` shell directly, even on a personal computer?"*  It's preferable because it prevents accidents.