# why have programs like su access to /etc/shadow

Tags: permissions, root, shadow

Normally only root can access `/etc/shadow`. But programs like `su` and `sudo` can check passwords without running as root. So the question is: Why can these programs access `/etc/shadow` without privileges? I tried to access it without privileges via python with the `spwd` module, but I didn't get access (like expected). Which mechanism do these programs use?

Comment: `sudo` and `su` _do_ run as root. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11285/how-does-sudo-work for the internals how all that goes down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> why have programs like su access to /etc/shadow

Because programs like `su` and `passwd` have set `SetUID`. You can check by using :

```
[root@tpserver tmp]#  ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-r-s--x--x  1 root root 21200 Aug 22  2013 /usr/bin/passwd
```

When you look around in your file permission you will see "s". If anybody is trying to run the `passwd` program, by default it's taking the privilege of owner (root here) of the file. This means any user can get root privilege to execute the `passwd` program, because only the root user can edit or update `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` file. Other users cant. When the normal user runs the `passwd` program on his terminal, the `passwd` program is run as "root", because the effective UID is set to "root". So the normal user can easily update the file.

You can use the `chmod` command with the `u+s` or `g+s` arguments to set the setuid and setgid bits on an executable file, respectively

---

**Long Answer : Set-User_Id (SUID): Power for a Moment:**

By default, when a user executes a file, the process which results in
this execution has the same permissions as those of the user. In fact,
the process inherits his default group and user identification.

If you set the SUID attribute on an executable file, the process resulting in its execution doesn't use the user's identification but the user identification of the file owner.

The SUID mechanism, invented by Dennis Ritchie, is a potential security hazard. It lets a user acquire hidden powers by running such a file owned by root.

```
$ ls -l /etc/passwd /etc/shadow /usr/bin/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2232 Mar 15 00:26 /etc/passwd
-r-------- 1 root root 1447 Mar 19 19:01 /etc/shadow
```

The listing shows that passwd is readable by all, but shadow is unreadable by group and others. When a user running the program belongs to one of these two categories (probably, others), so access fails in the read test on shadow. Suppose normal user wants to change his password. How can he do that? He can do that by running `/usr/bin/passwd`. Many UNIX/Linux programs have a special permission mode that lets users update sensitive system files –like `/etc/shadow` --something they can't do directly with an editor. This is true of the `passwd` program.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 22984 Jan 6 2007 /usr/bin/passwd
```

The s letter in the user category of the permission field represents a special mode known as the set-user-id (SUID). This mode lets a process have the privileges of the owner of the file during the instance of the program. Thus when a non privileged user executes passwd, the effective UID of the process is not the user's, but of root's – the owner of the program. This SUID privilege is then used by passwd to edit `/etc/shadow`.

[Reference Link](http://www.bashguru.com/2010/03/unixlinux-advanced-file-permissions.html)

Comment: Thanks! Now i finally also got what the S execution bit does.

Comment: `S` is actually different from `s`. `s` means: execute + setuid, while `S` means just setuid without execute. This ensures that you can tell if the respective user still has the execute permission, because the `s`/`S` flag uses the space that is normally used by the `x` flag.

Comment: The capital S indicates the file has a setuid bit set but is not executable.

Comment: Check more by using `info ls "What information is listed"`