# Sudo asks for password even after `sudo su` without pass

Tags: sudo, authentication

I have already `sudo`-ed to an account, by running `sudo su - <username>` and when I try to run `apt` from this account I am getting the  message:

```
[sudo] password for <username>:
```

which I don't have (!!!), since I was using `sudo su - <username>`, in order to work on behalf of account `<username>`, and without asking for password. Please note, that *I don't have root or credentials* for this server. Any help will be appreciated, since I am a bit newbie to *sudo internals*.

I have read this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441151/which-users-password-does-sudo-asks-for), but it does not really shed any light and trying to read `sudoers`, gives me `Access Denied`

**Edit:**

It turns out that `apt-get` etc. cannot be located, not even by which, thus some more work needs to be done but will try to install.

**Edit 2:**
I understand that the whole configuration, seems stupid to a lot of you, but that's what I was presented to operate with.

Comment: I think you should not use ```sudo su <user>```followed by ```sudo apt ...``` but ```sudo apt ...``` without changing to another user account. Why would you want to use this particular user account to execute something with ```sudo```?

Comment: You _do_ have root credentials on this server, because otherwise your `sudo su - <username>` couldn't work. Try `sudo -s` to be surprised. (Or if that fails, `sudo su - root`.)

Comment: You are right @roaima. `sudo apt-get` from my every account, gives me a `command not found` error, though

Comment: Relevant: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `sudo su username` or the more reasonable in most cases `sudo -u username`, all you are doing is starting a new shell as `username`. You aren't root, you're username, so in order to now run a `sudo` command as username, you will need username's password.

However, if what you want to do is run `apt`, then there's no point in logging in as username since only root can run it. All you need is to directly run `sudo apt ...` from your regular account and it will be the same as having run `sudo apt ...` as username.

Comment: Thank you @terdon. The think is that I was given this situation as granted, hinted to use `sudo su` to avoid root credentials as I see, and I am trying to install a few things using sudo, right now. Thank you for your answers, it turns out I am more newbie to Linux...

Comment: @YannisP. this is a personal pet peeve of mine, but don't use `sudo su`. Just use `sudu -i` or `sudo -s` to get a root shell. No big important reason, it's just inelegant to use two programs where one will do :). #spastikos

Comment: made a huge mistake and my distro is #RHEL thus have to use `yum` :(. Can't find some repos but we ll see

Answer (score -1):

If your user is already added in sudoers file , then do

1) sudo su , it will ask for password , you give your user password then it will go to your root accound , from there you can run 'apt ...'

2) sudo apt ... , it will ask for your password , give your user password  then it will execute the command .

Comment: Please don't carry on this `sudo su` silliness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have just made an edit. I didn't know to begin with, but it seems that I have to add `apt-get` etc.

Comment: Furthermore, once you are root there is absolutely no need to use `sudo` _again_ to run `apt`.

Comment: @roaima true, I also have to install `apt-get` but that's fine. Btw, I was presented with this situation and I don't really like it but that's how it is. Will see what can be done

Comment: @YannisP. there's no reason to install apt-get. If it isn't installed, you probably have `apt` and you can use that directly. Instead of `sudo apt-get install`, you can run `sudo apt install`. You might want to come into [dchat] if you have this sort of basic question. Might be easier to explain there.

Comment: @roaima : yeah but if you want to get root privilege, 'sudo su'  is the only way right OR you ask admin to do the installaiton ... :)

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar no! `sudo su` is like saying "_Hello `sudo`, please can I have root... ok thank you. Now, hello `su`. Although I'm already root please can I have root? What of course? Oh, thank you_". There is absolutely no need whatsoever to call `su` if you can use `sudo`. Just use `sudo -s` or for the more general situation `sudo {command...}`.

Comment: @roaima : I mentioned to go to root prompt ( i meant -> root@hostname#  prompt ) not to execute command , to execute command sudo { command } is fine.....

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar still no! You do not need to use `sudo` to run  root command if you are already root.

Comment: @roaima Yes! because i said when you are not in root. If you are already in root , no sense in using sudo....