# Can't enter in sudo on Debian 12

Tags: debian, virtualbox, root

I'm sitting on a Virtual Machine on Debian 12, the password for root is simple, it's the letter q, but when I write, say, sudo -i and enter the password, the terminal only displays Sorry, try again. The thing is that when I go into Rescue Mode and enter the password for the root user, everything works out. What should I do?

Comment: `sudo` is usually configured to ask for the invoking user's password, not root's - see for example [Which user's password does `sudo` asks for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441151/which-users-password-does-sudo-asks-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the root password, then the appropriate command to become root is

```
su
```

or, if you want a login shell,

```
su -
```

This will ask you for the root password. `sudo` expects the user’s password, and has to be configured appropriately; in many cases it isn’t set up by default on Debian systems (especially when a root password is defined).

Answer (score -2):

have you tried running `journalctl --system -b`
should hopefully help you identify what is going on. sudo -i should prompt you for *user pass* while sudo -s should prompt you for root password

Comment: No, `sudo -s` also prompts for the user password.