# Why can't I `su postgres`?

Tags: users, su, postgresql

1. I wonder why when I provide root's password, the following command
   reports failure?

   ```
   $ su postgres
   Password: 
   su: Authentication failure
   ```

   Is it correct that [`su` asks for the password of root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11287/674), not of
   `postgres`?

   If it is the password of `postgres`, when I installed postgreSQL, I didn't set up a login name to connect to postgresql server, and I didn't explicitly create the user `postgres` on my Ubuntu, so what is its password?

   in `/etc/passwd`

   ```
   postgres:x:124:133:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
   ```

   in `/etc/shadow`:

   ```
   postgres:*:17478:0:99999:7:::
   ```
2. If I indeed can't `su postgres`, then generally speaking, what  target users can `su`   switch to?

   Is it
   correct that they are also the users whose ids setuid() can take as
   argument?

   From APUE, I learned that login names without valid login shell command can't be used for login. Are they also can be `su`ed to?  But `postgres` has a valid login shell command `/bin/bash`, so why can't I `su postgres`?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But why does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11287/674  say that "su requires root's password"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the second field of `/etc/shadow`:

```
postgres:*:17478:0:99999:7:::
```

Normally it would have the encrypted password, but here it has just a single asterisk. That means the account is locked - no password will be acceptable for it. This is the state any new account will have until a password is assigned to it.

To transition into a user account that is currently locked, you would need a transition method that does not ask for the password of the target account. For `su`, that would mean you would have to fully become root first.

It would be possible to configure `sudo` to allow you access to the `postgres` account even though it is locked for password authentication. The `/etc/sudoers` line would be something like this:

```
Tim     ALL=(postgres) ALL
```

The `sudo` command line equivalent to `su postgres` would be `sudo -u postgres -s`. Note: in this method, some environment settings from your original account may be still in use in your session as user `postgres`. You may or may not want that: it could be actually useful if you have two or more database administrators with different personal preferences for their shell/environment both `sudo`ing to the `postgres` account.

If you want the environment to be exactly as if it would be if user `postgres` would have when logged in directly, you could also use `sudo -u postgres -i` (the equivalent of `su - postgres`).

But if you want to have `su postgres` work, you would just need to have a password set for the user `postgres`. That can be achieved by running `passwd postgres` as root.

Comment: Thanks. "Normally it would have the encrypted password, but here it has just a single asterisk. That means the account is locked - no password will be acceptable for it."  What  programs or kernel do you mean that accept no password  for the user?

Comment: In this question I was talking about `su`, but my point stands for anything that uses `pam_unix.so` for checking the user's password. You still get asked for a password as usual, and can enter anything, but my point was that *you cannot get through the password check* no matter what you enter: at this point all the passwords are wrong ones for this account. The unix-style password checking works by running the user input through the same hashing algorithm as the stored password and seeing if the result matches; but the asterisk is not part of the output character set of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You should not give the postgres user a password.  This is considered a security flaw as someone can now login as that user and do whatever they want.  Instead, you should give yourself sudo permission on this user and use constructs like the following.

```
sudo -u postgres psql ...
```