# su vs sudo -s vs sudo -i vs sudo bash

Tags: sudo, su

What is the difference between the following commands:

```
su
sudo -s
sudo -i
sudo bash
```

I know for `su` I need to know the root password, and for `sudo` I have to be in the `sudoers` file, but once executed what is difference?

I know there is a difference between `su` and `sudo -s` because my home directory is `/root` after I execute `su`, but my home directory is still `/home/myname` after `sudo -s`. But I suspect this is just a symptom of an underlying difference that I'm missing.

Comment: I prefer to use `sudo su -` 
This way you don't need the root password, and the `-` makes sure the home directory is set right.

Comment: See also [Which is the safest way to get root privileges: sudo, su or login?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/which-is-the-safest-way-to-get-root-privileges-sudo-su-or-login)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

With `su`, you *become* another user — root by default, but potentially another user. If you say `su -`, your environment gets replaced with that user's login environment as well, so that what you see is indistinguishable from logging in as that user. There is no way the system can tell what you do while `su`'d to another user from actions by that user when they log in.

Things are very different with `sudo`:

- Commands you run through `sudo` *execute* as the target user — root by default, but changeable with `-u` — but it logs the commands you run through it, tagging them with your username so blame can be assigned afterward. :)
- `sudo` is very flexible. You can limit the commands a given user or group of users are allowed to run, for example. With `su`, it's all or nothing.

  This feature is typically used to define roles. For instance, you could define a "backups" group allowed to run `dump` and `tar`, each of which needs root access to properly back up the system disk.

  I mention this here because it means you can give someone `sudo` privileges without giving them `sudo -s` or `sudo bash` abilities. They have only the permissions they need to do their job, whereas with `su` they have run of the entire system. You have to be careful with this, though: if you give someone the ability to say `sudo vi`, for example, they can shell out of `vi` and have effectively the same power as with `sudo -s`.
- Because it takes the sudoer's password instead of the root password, `sudo` isolates permission between multiple sudoers.

  This solves an administrative problem with `su`,  which is that when the root password changes, all those who had to know it to use `su` had to be told. `sudo` allows the sudoers' passwords to change independently. In fact, it is common to password-lock the root user's account on a system with `sudo` to force all sysadmin tasks to be done via `sudo`. In a large organization with many trusted sudoers, this means when one of the sysadmins leaves, you don't have to change the root password and distribute it to those admins who remain.

The main differences between `sudo bash` and `sudo -s` are:

1. `-s` is shorter than `bash`
2. You can say `sudo -s some-command` to run `some-command` under your default shell, but with superuser privileges. It's basically shorthand for `sudo $SHELL -c some-command`.
3. You can instead pass the commands to the shell's standard input, like `sudo -s < my-shell-script`. You could use this with a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to send several commands to a single `sudo` call, avoiding the need to type `sudo` repeatedly.
4. Even without these extra command arguments, `sudo -s` still differs from `sudo bash` in that it might run a different shell than `bash`, since it looks first in the `SHELL` environment variable, and then if that is unset, at your user's login shell setting, typically in `/etc/passwd`.

The shell run by `sudo -s` inherits your current user environment. If what you actually want is a clean environment, like you get just after login, what you want instead is `sudo -i`, a relatively recent addition to `sudo`. Roughly speaking, `sudo -i` is to `sudo -s` as `su -` is to `su`: it resets all but a few key environment variables and sends you back to your user's home directory. If you don't also give it commands to run under that shell via standard input or `sudo -i some-command`, it will run that shell as an interactive login shell, so your user's shell startup scripts (e.g. `.bash_profile`) get run again.

All of this makes `sudo -i` considerably more secure than `sudo -s`. Why? Because if someone can modify your environment before `sudo -s`, they could cause unintended commands to be executed. The most obvious case is modifying `SHELL`, but it can also happen less directly, such as via `PAGER` if you say `man foo` while under `sudo -s`.

You might say, "If they can modify `PAGER`, they can modify `PATH`, and then they can just substitute an evil `sudo` program," but someone sufficiently paranoid can say `/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash` to avoid that trap. You're probably not so paranoid that you also avoid the traps in all the *other* susceptible environment variables, though. Did you also remember to check `EDITOR`, for example, before running any [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) command? Thus `sudo -i`.

Because `sudo -i` also changes your working directory to your user's home directory, you might still want to use `sudo -s` for those situations where you know you want to remain in the same directory you were `cd`'d into when you ran `sudo`. It's still safer to `sudo -i` and `cd` back to where you were, though.

Another variant of all this that you sometimes see is `sudo su`, which is approximately equivalent to `sudo -s`. Likewise, `sudo su -` is functionally quite close to `sudo -i`. Since `sudo` and `su` are competing commands, it's a little odd to pair them like this, so I recommend that you use the `sudo` flags instead.

Comment: What do you mean by 'shell out of vi'?

Comment: @crisron: From within `vi`, type `:sh` and hit Enter. Now you're in a sub-shell, with all the privileges of the `vi` process that spawned that shell. If `vi` is running with root privileges, so will the shell. Or, you can run something other than a shell via `:!cmd`, read output from a command into the edit buffer via `:r !cmd`, etc. If all those are locked down, `Makefile` targets are shell scripts, and Vim has the `:make` command, which effectively lets you run arbitrary shell scripts from within the editor. The possibilities for mischief are far too immense for this comment box to hold.

Comment: if someone can put a fake in bash in your PATH then that someone can put a fake sudo in your PATH. to be really sure you have to invoke sudo using the full path: `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: @lesmana: I've addressed that in an edit; basically, the `PATH` isn't the only problem.

Comment: Great explanation; great headache reading it.

Comment: @lobi is right, unfortunately.  But aside from that, there's an aspect I don't see covered here: is there any advantage to using `sudo su -`?

Comment: @Wildcard: Extra geek points the next time you level up in the Unix [RTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_strategy). Out here [IRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_life), simple and effective beats cute and clever.

Comment: That was a serious question, actually.  I know several experienced sysadmins who use `sudo su -` and I'm wondering why.  I don't understand your last comment at all.  (Like, at *all* at all; it's totally baffling.  Geek points?  Unix RTS?  IRL vs. cute and clever?  I've no idea at all what to make of it or even what tone I should read it in.)

Comment: I'm saying you're getting the same effect with more keystrokes. A video game might score you higher for such flourishes, but you get no extra points for it as a working sysadmin.

Comment: @WarrenYoung lol, I get it. :)

Comment: Old answer, but this can not be upvoted enough times.  Incredible explanation.

Answer (score 30):

From an [ubuntuforums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6188826&postcount=4) I made a while ago:

Consider the following experiment:

```
applic@ion:~% sudo su
[sudo] password for applic:
root@ion:/home/applic# env > /tmp/sudo_su_env
root@ion:/home/applic# exit
exit
applic@ion:~% sudo -s
applic .bashrc read...
root@ion:~% env >/tmp/sudo_s
```

Here are the differences I found:

With `sudo -s`:

```
HOME=/home/applic
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
reads $USER's ~/.bashrc
```

With `sudo su`:

```
HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
reads /etc/environment
reads /root/.bashrc
```

Notice the difference in `$HOME`. Being root and having `$HOME` set to the normal user's home can cause problems. For example, if you run a graphical app, the normal user's `~/.Xauthority` can get overwritten by root. This causes the normal user problems later on such as not being able to run certain graphical apps through cron.

To summarize:

```
                                     corrupted by user's 
        HOME=/root  uses root's PATH     env vars
sudo -i     Y       Y[2]                 N
sudo -s     N       Y[2]                 Y
sudo bash   N       Y[2]                 Y
sudo su     Y       N[1]                 Y
```

1. `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`
       probably set by `/etc/environment`
2. `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin`

The bottom line is `sudo -i` is the proper command to run when you want a root shell that is untainted by the user's environment.

Comment: How much the environment is 'tainted' depends on the configuration of `sudo` (in `/etc/sudoers` and related files) as well. Configuration settings such as `always_set_home`, `env_reset`, `env_keep`, `env_check` and `env_reset`, and these may vary depending on the user and command. See the ['Command environment'](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.21/sudoers.man.html#Command_environment) and [SUDOERS OPTIONS](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.21/sudoers.man.html#SUDOERS_OPTIONS) section of of the _sudoers(5)_ manpage.

Comment: Personally, I go with `sudo -Hs` when I want an environment untainted by my settings, because I use zsh and all of the application accounts I might be changing to use bash. This does let a certain number of environment variables pass unmolested, but I typically find the ones that matter get overwritten by /etc/profile.d/*.

Comment: There is no reason for `sudo su` **ever**. Please stop typing it and publishing it.

Answer (score 12):

`su` (**s**witch **u**ser or **s**ubstitute **u**ser) lets you switch user. `su` basically starts another shell instance with the privileges of the intended user. By default it switches you to the `root` user, if we want to switch specific user we need to pass user as follows:

```
$ su bob  # switches to bob (requires bob's password)
```

`su -` means environment variables will be reset to root and `su` means environment variables as old user.

for example:  root's home directory if you use `su -` or old user home directory if you use `su`.

sudo (**s**uper **u**ser **do**) is a command-line utility that allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default is  superuser i.e `root`. It uses a config file `/etc/sudoers` which lists which users have rights to specific actions

sudo should be read as **/ˈsuːduː/**. syntax `sudo command` i.e. **s**witch **u**ser and **do** this command.

- `su` is equivalent to `sudo -i` and  simulates a login into the root account. Your working directory will be `/root`, and it will read root's `.profile` etc. The prompt will change from $ to #, indicating you have root access.
- `sudo -s`  launches a shell as root, but doesn't change your working
  directory.
- `sudo bash`  where `bash` is command to run with `sudo`. This command runs
  `bash` as a super user.
- Using `sudo` can be logged everything someone does.
- Using `sudo` prevents a user from having to know the root password.
- Using `sudo` we can limit the commands are allowed to run.

Comment: a plain `su` doesn't change working directory.