# Deference between command "sudo su ls" vs "sudo ls"

Tags: command

I saw some command such as `sudo su ls`, and I just wonder what's the deference between `sudo ls`?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/ddg#376386) is a good explanation of the difference between sudo, su, sudo -i, sudo su, etc.

Comment: A similar question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145873/ .

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the commands you mentioned perform two different tasks.

- `su` is a program used to switch to another user. If you execute `su <user>` you start a shell session as another *user*.
- `sudo` allows you to run a single command as the root user.
- `sudo su` allows you to run `su` as the root. If you execute `sudo su <user>` you start a shell session as the *user*.

Then,

- `sudo su ls` will start a shell as the `ls` user, if it exists.
- `sudo ls` will list the content of directory just like if the command was issued by the root user.

If you are interested on two equivalent commands, you may consider...

```
sudo bash -c "ls"       # execute "ls" as the root
sudo ls                 # execute "ls" as the root
```

Comment: `sudo` allows you to do anything `su` can do, and more. `su` has been obsoleted by `sudo`.