# Permissions for new user

Tags: permissions, non-root-user, vps

I have created a user in my Centos VPS. But with the new user I can not create, modify files in any folder (for example `/var/www/` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`), even though I have added the new user to the wheel group. (My explanation might be wrong since my knowledge of linux is very low.)

How can I configure this user to work as if it were root?

> First I created the user

```
$ useradd mynewuser
$ passwd mynewuser
```

> Then I added root privileges:

```
$ usermod -G wheel mynewuser  
$ vi /etc/pam.d/su

# Uncommented this line  
auth            required        pam_wheel.so use_uid

$ visudo
mynewuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use commands `su` or `sudo`. Just adding user to group `wheel` or adding in `sudoers` is not enough.

The `su` command switches to the root user – when you execute it with no additional options. You will have to enter the root account’s password. This isn’t all the su command does. You can use it to switch to any user account.
If you execute the `su john`, you will be prompted to enter john’s password and the shell will switch to john’s user account. Once you're done running commands in the root shell, you should type exit to leave the root shell and go back to limited-privileges mode.

`sudo` runs a single command with root privileges. When you execute `sudo command`, the system prompts you for your current user account's password before running command as the root user.

More you can find in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-bash) about difference between `su` and `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question. Does it means that to create a folder I always have to run: "sudo mkdir name"? I'm using Capistrano and some tasks that don't use sudo cause errors. (like "mkdir name")

Comment: Yes, you do if you want it to be created with root permissions.