# Keyboard doesn't work with su

Tags: osx, sudo, keyboard, su

I try to open an app in OSX — let's say Notes for instance, I use two commands in terminal to switch to other user:

```
sudo -u user /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes
```

this opens `Notes` as `user`, I can type, click and use normally as `user`

If I use `su`

```
 su - user
```

then launch the app

```
/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes
```

It does launch the app, but the keyboard does not work; why is this? Can you pour some insight into this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [su vs sudo -s vs sudo -i vs sudo bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bash)

Comment: @muru, I thought so at first too, but I don't think the answer on that question explains why the keyboard wouldn't work with `su`.  Maybe I missed it?

Comment: @Jesse_b some macOS-specific environment variable that doesn't get carried over to login shells. Does it matter which?

Comment: At any rate, [help/on-topic] says: "The Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)" ... so dupe or off-topic.

Comment: Justin, can you use `su - user` to open another application and see if the keyboard works with it?