# How to avoid nesting root shells? (POSIX)

Tags: shell, sudo, root, alias

Consider the following Bash alias, just something that came to mind quickly, and I did not have time to dig further:

```bash
alias su='sudo -s'
```

Note, that I am running Bash, though I would like the solution to be portable as I will likely post it to GitHub at some point to share it.

The problem one might encounter is running it (that alias) while already root.

Demo:

```
$ su
[sudo] password for vlastimil:                
# su
# su
# 
exit
# 
exit
# 
exit
$
```

---

Is there a way to avoid the nested shell sessions?

Important note: I am using the same alias file for my user and root, not separate. The solution must be portable (POSIX).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`su` and `sudo -s` are different commands with different APIs, semantic, and behavior, you shouldn't alias one to the other.

Here it seems you want a command that starts `root`'s login shell as `root` via `sudo` but only when invoked from a non-privileged shell, so I would write a script called `rootshell` for instance as:

```
#! /bin/sh -

die() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}

[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || die "Usage: $0

Starts a root shell, no argument accepted."

[ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ] && die "You're already superuser!"

exec sudo -s
```

Add `-u root` to the `sudo` command (or the name a user with uid 0 on your system), if that's not the default target user in your system's `sudo` configuration.

Or if you don't want to make a script, make it a shell function by wrapping that code as `rootshell() (<that-code>)` to add in your shell rc file (change `$0` to the name of the function as not all shells put the function name in `$0`).

Comment: Why there is `exec` I know little of it, go easy on me. Thanks.

Comment: To reduce the number of shells: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec _If exec is specified with command, it shall replace the shell with command without creating a new process_

Answer (score 1):

### Simplistic solution, a shell alias

```bash
alias su='[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ] && sudo -s || echo Already root...'
```

---

- POSIX-compatible, which means if you copy-paste it to `dash` or I suppose almost any other shell-supporting aliases, you should get the same behavior.
- That is also why I avoided `EUID` and direct value comparison altogether.

---

Demo:

```
$ su
[sudo] password for vlastimil:                
# su
Already root...
# su
Already root...
# 
exit
$
```

---

<sub>Considering I use `sudo -s`, I attach [its comparison with `sudo -s` vs other variants](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bash).</sub>

---

### Advanced solution, a shell script (POSIX)

Since I used the pseudo-solution above, the alias, for a very long time (years), I also have become aware of its disadvantages. Which is why I just posted a script to Code Review based upon [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas), the [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/287639/104270) and a respective [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287641/104270) can be found there. Here I place the very script I intend to use from now onward:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -o nounset -o errexit

error()
{
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

is_root()
{
    [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
}

start_root_shell()
{
    exec sudo -s
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    error "Usage of $(basename "$0") script:" \
    '' \
    'Starts a root shell, no argument accepted.'
fi

if is_root
then
    error 'You are already superuser!'
fi

start_root_shell
```

Thank you [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Two parts to this answer, both reliant on editing the `sudoers` file. (I'm not sure how to answer this with POSIX compliance as neither `sudo` nor `bash` used in your example are POSIX. However, the solution should be portable across systems that use these tools.)

1. You can simplify your use of `sudo` and avoid the alias by setting the boolean variable `shell_noargs` in the `/etc/sudoers` file. You can now use `sudo` to access a root shell instead of `sudo -s`.
2. Some shells such as `bash` allow you to keep track of the shell level through a variable such as `$SHLVL`. This can be tracked through `sudo` invocations as well as through simply typing `bash`. Adding this to your shell prompt will help you identify how many levels of nesting you currently have.

Create our own `sudoers` file rather than editing the system-provided one:

```
sudo EDITOR=nano visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/local
```

Add these lines to the file and save it

```
# Allow sudo with no args to create a shell
Defaults        shell_noargs

# Allow bash to share its nesting level
Defaults        env_check+="SHLVL"
```

For `bash`, go to your `~/.bashrc` (and maybe either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`) and find the line that defines `PS1`. Modify it to include `$SHLVL`. For example, on my Debian system it's set like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$ '
```

I would modify it to include `$SHLVL` like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h[$SHLVL]:\W\$ '
```

Finally, repeat the edit for root's configuration file(s).

Note, if you're using a shell other than `bash` that does not provide `$SHLVL` it's trivial to implement *provided* that the shell runs a configuration file each time it starts. (POSIX `sh` does not, unfortunately.)