# Does "sudo" rely on "su" in any way?

Tags: sudo, su

I want to prevent the users from using the `su` command, and so I blocked the command in `/etc/sudoers` file as below:

```
%group ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:!/bin/su
```

But with this rule in `sudoers`, they are unable to execute `sudo <command>` commands, resulting in the error:

```
Sorry, user xxxx is not allowed to execute 'command' as root on <host>
```

Is there any way that the program `sudo` relies on `su`?

Comment: Related: [su vs sudo -s vs sudo -i vs sudo bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35338) (see also the "Linked questions" on that question, as well as [other questions relating to `sudo` and `su`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/su%2bsudo?tab=Frequent)).

Comment: This seems like it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). Setting up sudo as "people can do anything except Foo as root" is almost always the wrong thing to do. Why exactly are you trying to do that?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Indeed.  It's almost impossible to give someone "just a little bit of root".  "Well, they need to edit this one file, I'll set up `/etc/sudoers` so they can run `vi`."  User starts `vi` via `sudo` and then enters `:!/bin/bash`.  Instant `root` shell.  That's just one example.  That's why there's auditing...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sudo` doesn’t rely on `su`.

Your setup prevents users from running anything because it doesn’t grant anything: it only prevents users from using `/bin/su`. You’d need `NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/su` or something to that effect.

Note however that denying `/bin/su` in this way won’t stop users from copying `su` somewhere else and running the copy. See [the relevant discussion](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Limitations_of_the_!) in `man sudoers`.

Comment: My bad! You are absolutely right!

Comment: There are lots of other holes by which users with sudo privileges can get root access even when su is denied. `sudo sudo`, `sudo bash`, `sudo vi` `sudo less`, `sudo chmod`.....

Comment: @symcbean or just `sudo -s`.

Comment: Copying `su` isn't likely - or at least if it is then either the SUID bit will get dropped or the user already had root access

Comment: @roaima given that the intention was `ALL=(ALL:ALL)` I think it’s safe to assume that the user already has root access.

Comment: @symcbean: `sudo cp $HOME/vmlinuz /boot/vmlinuz`

Comment: @roaima They can do `sudo chmod u+s su_copy`

Comment: @Barmar they don’t even need to, `sudo su_copy` will run `su_copy` as root so it doesn’t need to be setuid.

Comment: @Joshua I take it you don’t use Secure Boot.

Comment: True, the popular `sudo su` idiom is weird to begin with.

Comment: @StephenKitt: You're right, I don't. According to the manual I would just also need to do `sudo sbsign` as well.

Comment: @Joshua you’d need to either know the passphrase for one of the system’s MOKs, or enroll a new one (assuming you have physical access to the system and know the appropriate setup password; but if that’s the case you already own the system anyway).

Comment: @Barmar Yes `sudo su` would be weird, but the idiom was actually `sudo su -` and its popularity was well deserved. It's almost a real login (all the startup scripts, login shell, etc.) and it was a useful shorthand back when `sudo -i` didn't exist. The behavior of  `sudo -s` is/was quite different.

Comment: No need to copy `su`, `sudo env su`, `sudo sh -c su` would be enough to run `su` (assuming the `noexec` sudo feature is not used).

Answer (score -1):

Make the su password impossible to guess and you get the same affect. Though you might want to prevent the password from being being changed that way.

Comment: `su` doesn't prompt for a password when invoked as `root` like with `sudo su`