# sudo -i is behaving differently than sudo su -

Tags: sudo, prompt, su

If I as a non-root user (but in the sudoers file) do `sudo -i`, I get root privileges:

```
laptop:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for bjmgeek: 
laptop:~$ whoami
root
laptop:~$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
laptop:~$
```

But, notice the prompt still shows a `$` (which typically means a normal user), not a `#` (which typically means root).

If, however, I do `sudo su -`, I also become root, but get the # prompt:

```
laptop:~$ sudo su -
-bash-5.2# whoami
root
-bash-5.2# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

According to the man page, `su -` starts the shell as a login shell.  And, according to the man page, `sudo -i` starts the shell as a login shell.  So, what's the difference that one gets the prompt, with a `#`, and one gets the prompt with a `$` ?

This is on a Debian system, but I don't think there's anything debian-specific about the `su` or `sudo` commands.

I wonder if it is specifically related to `\$` which should show a # for root, and a $ for non-root users.

Update: `$PS1` for `sudo -i` is set to `\h:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$` instead of ending in a `\$`, so that's the cause of the problem.  Now I just need to comb through all my files to see what's not setting it correctly.

Comment: What prompt do you get with `sudo -s`? What happens if you first clear your prompt with `PS1='$ '`, and then run `sudo -i`?

Comment: Related if not a duplicate, [su vs sudo -s vs sudo -i vs sudo bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35338/100397)

Comment: `sudo -i` sets `$SUDO_USER` whereas `sudo su -` does not. Do you have anything in root's `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` (etc.) that sets the prompt depending on `$SUDO_USER`?

Comment: @ChrisDavies No, there's nothing mentioning SUDO_USER in root's .bashrc or .bash_profile.

Comment: @terdon sudo -s shows a normal user prompt.

Comment: Please [edit] and add that to your question (and clarify if "normal" means what you want or not).

Comment: @terdon by "normal user", I meant non-root.  I updated the question to better reflect this.