# Return status of `cd` is always 0

Tags: bash

I am executing following command.

```
cd dirname; echo $?
```

This always return `0` whether of not cd is successful. This is giving me incredible headache.

How to check if cd was successful without reading its error message.

Comment: Strange.  I'm not seeing that behavior on Linux with bash 4.2.39.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in bash 4.2.37 on Ubuntu; it will return 1 for me if I try to `cd` to a nonexistent directory as expected. What version are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce on bash 4.2.45(1) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with 4.2.42, too.

Comment: Just to be sure: What is the output of `type cd`?

Comment: What version of bash (`bash --version`) are you using? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Not seeing this on OS X, CentOS, raspbian, or netBSD.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks. On lab machine, it was already aliased to keep_cd_history. Will check it on my personal machine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason may be that `cd` is not a shell builtin as usual but

1. a shell function
2. or an alias

This can be checked with `type cd`.

(I make the comment an answer so that the question can be "closed".)

Answer (score 3):

My stupidity!

As suggested by HaukeLaging, I did `type cd`. It turned out the `cd` was aliased to some bash function which was logging the user `cd` activity on the server.

I aliased `cd` back to `cd` and the script started working fine. I had the fleeting temptation to delete the question altogether first the I thought I should answer it here. I might be useful for someone else.

Comment: I would suggest checking all aliases on your account. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/which-is-the-safest-way-to-get-root-privileges-sudo-su-or-login (there is worse) ... also whatever did it accidentally could have done it twice.

Comment: Also think about using `\cd` to override the alias.

Comment: To remove an alias: `unalias cd`. To remove a function: `unset -f cd`. To  call the builtin `cd`, in `bash` and a few other shells: `builtin cd` (`\cd` would bypass aliases but not functions). `command cd` would call the builtin `cd` in POSIX shells, but the `cd` command in `zsh` (when not in POSIX mode).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to prefix the call w/ the bash builtin 'command'. This will force the use of the actual binary file 'cd'

```
    root@ds002:~# command cd /foo
    -bash: cd: /foo: No such file or directory
    root@ds002:~# echo $?
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. As all others mentioning, it was because my "cd" was wrapped by a function.

Anyway, this should be worked.

```
command cd /mnt/c/nowhere && echo y # does not console "y"
```