# Can sudo replace su?

Tags: sudo, authentication, su, accounts

There is much duplication of functionality on Linux-based systems, for example these do the same thing:

```
sudo --login --user <user>
sudo su - <user>
```

The **`sudo`**-only approach looks more elegant. Can one do without **`su`** without breaking too many things?

Comment: You mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094826/how-to-give-a-linux-user-sudo-access ?

Comment: I would assume su is part of the POSIX standard while sudo is not. Removing programs that are guaranteed to be available on a system by POSIX  is risky IMO.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not wrong, there are some slight differences between `su` and `sudo`:

- `su` only allows changing the user id (to become superuser for example).
- `su` allows any user that knows the password of another user to become that user, and there is no way to control this.
- `sudo` allows running a command as another user (including root).
- `sudo` is controlled by the `/etc/sudoers` file.

I think the initial goal of the `sudo` command is to have a better control of who can run commands with root privileges and who cannot. When you have a system with more than one administrator, `sudo` allows running commands as root without needing the root password, which is from my point of view, more secure. On many distributions, the `/etc/sudoers` allows to control the user or group list that can use `sudo`.

Comment: Looks like there is no case where **su** is technically superior?

Comment: ^ Using `su` means not having to configure `/etc/sudoers`, so it is simpler and easier. ^

Answer (score 3):

In usage, yes, sudo can completely replace su. But there are a lot of scripts and programs that use `su`, so there is no way to safely remove it. 
Lots of Linux distrubutions don't have sudo preinstalled. Using sudo in a script will make it incompatible with these systems. As Jernej mentioned in his comment, su is part of the Posix standard. That means that when you write a script you should be able to trust that if you use 
`su` your script will run on all Posix compliant operating systems.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Fully_POSIX-compliant) is a reference.

Comment: So, all it would need for **sudo** to replace **su** in a sane manner is to update POSIX? No corner cases where **sudo** would be less suitable?

Comment: I would have to go through the man pages in detail to make sure, but I have never seen a case where you have to use su because sudo is unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` closes any file descriptors greater than `>&2` for invoked processes automatically - which might be a problem.

The whole `sudoers` thing is yet another *(arguably unnecessary)* abstraction from the tried and true `/etc/passwd` basic user/group Unix-style permissions scheme and it requires its own management.

For instance, [from `man growisofs`](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/growisofs.1m.html):

> If executed under `sudo(8) growisofs` refuses to start. This is done for the following reason. Naturally `growisofs` has to access the data set to be recorded to DVD media, either indirectly by letting `mkisofs` generate *ISO9660* layout on-the-fly or directly if a pre-mastered image is to be recorded. Being executed under `sudo(8)`, `growisofs` effectively grants `sudoers` read access to any file in the file system. The situation is intensified by the fact that `growisofs` parses `$MKISOFS` environment variable in order to determine alternative path to `mkisofs` executable image. This means that being executed under `sudo(8)`, `growisofs` effectively grants `sudoers` right to execute program of their choice with elevated privileges. If you for any reason still find the above acceptable and are willing to take the consequences, then consider running following wrapper script under `sudo(8)` in place for real `growisofs` binary.

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    unset SUDO_COMMAND
    export MKISOFS=/path/to/trusted/mkisofs
    exec growisofs "$@"
```

> But note that the recommended alternative to the above "workaround" is actually to install `growisofs` `set-root-uid`, in which case it will drop privileges prior accessing data or executing `mkisofs` in order to preclude unauthorized access to the data.

At least `su` actually temporarily switches users and preserves Unix-style permissions. `sudo`, on the other hand, *transcends* users. Still, if you properly cope with that in `/etc/sudoers` `sudo` can probably completely replace `su` in most respects and do so conveniently - with some minimal cost to security, because `su` presents most of the same security problems as `sudo` - and maybe a few of its own. I consider [this an excellent discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8581/52934) on the subject.

But why not just skip them both and...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>

```
login: root
```

Or...

```
ssh root@localhost
```

Whatever happened to *root* anyway?