# When in debian 8.1 why is the super user run with su not sudo?

Tags: debian, sudo, su

I am curious why the super user command `su` is run and not super user do (`sudo`).

Comment: Run where and when?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`su` and `sudo` are the two most common ways to run a program (possibly a shell) as another user (possibly root). They have the same effect, but they work very differently in terms of how they determine whether to allow the action:

- `su` requires that either the source user is root, or the user demonstrate that they have access to the target account (typically by typing a password).
- `sudo` requires pre-authorization: the combination of source user, target user and command must be declared in its configuration file.

`su` came first: it existed as far back as [Unix V3](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man8/su.8) in 1973. Back then it only covered the case of becoming root (hence the name: **s**uper-**u**ser). `sudo` came a bit later [in 1980](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/history.html), to add the possibility of defining complex authorization policies. Because `su` is older and simpler, it's a standard tool, available on all unix-like systems, while `sudo`, while a very common add-on, is often missing from default installations and embedded systems.

Debian defaults to `su` because it's part of the base system — under Linux, there's an `su` program both in [GNU Coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) (along with `ls`, `cp`, etc.) and in [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) (along with `mount`, `fdisk`, `taskset`, etc.). Many system scripts that run as root use `su` to launch tasks as a system user. The `sudo` package is optional because you can run a system without it, it's an end-user tool, rarely used by other software.

In terms of security, see [Which is the safest way to get root privileges: sudo, su or login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/which-is-the-safest-way-to-get-root-privileges-sudo-su-or-login)

Comment: At least on my system, `su` is neither in the `coreutils` nor in `util-linux` packages, but in `login` (which *is* part of the base system, so your main point is uneffected).

Comment: Most common occurrence of a linux/unix install without sudo is on embedded systems where disk space is at an absolute premium.

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is an additional program which may or may not be installed on a system. It's available as package `sudo` on Debian.  Without more information on the specific situation/code you are referring to, the most likely answer is that sudo cannot be assumed to be installed, why `su` is <del>required to be present as by the POSIX standard</del> installed as part of Debians base system. Any script or tutorial striving for maximum portability will hence use `su`.

Comment: `su` is not defined in POSIX.

Comment: @Gilles Had too look it up again, and you are right.  I stand corrected.  Funny story: if one googles *"su posix"*, one of the first hits is a [SO answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24251474/2425163) you gave, stating that *"If it's POSIX you want, then su is your only option"*.  I'm confused.

Comment: This answered it... it is an additional program not in the system yet...